# Textmate + Latexmk

Tags: mactex, latexmk, textmate

Textmate for OS X, has a LaTeX bundle (a great bundle indeed). But this bundle packs the latexmk script (version 3.7 or so), I am wondering if anyone was able to update the latexmk version that comes within the bundle, or even to have it use the system's version of it.

PS: I know this is not *TeX related issue, but I though there might be someone with a solution around here. Moderators may delete this if its against the rules.

Comment: I think your question is fine, and definitely on-topic.

Comment: Totally agree with Juan here: well within the range of topics that {TeX} covers.

Comment: Thank you Juan and Joseph. And Hendrik for tidying up my question :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, I have changed the bundled version of latexmk to a symbolic link to TexLive's version.  This works well, but is slightly difficult to instruct how to do as there are many potential locations for your LaTeX.tmbundle.

Personally, I recommend grabbing the [latest version from GitHub](https://github.com/textmate/latex.tmbundle) and placing it in `~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/` manually.  Then, you can delete the `~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/LaTeX.tmbundle/Support/bin/latexmk.pl` file, and replace it with a symbolic link to TeXLive's version:

```
ln -s /usr/texbin/latexmk ~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/LaTeX.tmbundle/Support/bin/latexmk.pl
```

There are other methods (you could do this directly within TextMate.app), but this is nice as it doesn't modify the original and if you use `git` then it tracks the changes you make, too.

Comment: I have to thank you. It worked. I use git too :)

Answer (score 5):

TextMate users will most likely be able to figure this out for themselves, but just a small update to the accepted answer:

TextMate places its [user-installed bundles](http://manual.macromates.com/en/bundles#editing_default_bundles_items) in `~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/` (as opposed to `~/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/`.)  So a complete solution (assuming git is installed) would be more like

```
$ mkdir -p "~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles"
$ cd !$
$ git clone https://github.com/textmate/latex.tmbundle.git
$ cd latex.tmbundle/Support/bin
$ mv latexmk.pl latexmk.pl.orig # just in case
$ ln -s /usr/texbin/latexmk latexmk.pl
```

Comment: I have changed the accepted answer. Good observation!