# Getting TextMate to call biber

Tags: automation, biber, textmate

I've recently made the switch to `biblatex` from `natbib` but one problem I've been unable to resolve is how to make TextMate (which is my preferred editor) call `biber` instead of `bibtex`. I've installed the updated `latex.tmbundle` from Github, but whenever I typeset, I get unresolved references, and only the reference codes show up in the typeset document, which looks fine otherwise.

I know that `biber` is working, for two reasons:

1. When I typeset in TeXShop, my document comes out looking exactly as it should, with fully parsed references;
2. When I run the `biber <file>` command in terminal on the `.bcf` file that TextMate initially generates and then TypeSet in TextMate afterward, everything works as it should.

Any help getting TextMate to call `biber` automatically would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm also working with TextMate and in my LaTeX preferences (those of the LaTeX-Bundle) i enabled `latexmk.pl`, which is for example explained here http://blog.mixable.de/textmate-und-latex/ (but only in german).
With TeX Live 2011 and 2012 `latexmk.pl` should be able to determine itself whether to run biblatex or biber, which is stated here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27450/how-to-make-latexmk-work-with-xelatex-and-biber . Though, if you could provide an MWE, that would be great, because i'm not used to `biber`.

Comment: @Ronny, Your solution worked. I also ended up replacing the `latexmk.pl` file with a symbolic link to TeX Live 2012's version, as described here: [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10107/textmate-latexmk/10114#10114). The only problem I'm still facing is that the `TypeSet & View` command in TextMate does not produce a TypeSet & View window or call Skim. All of the parsing is correct, however.

Comment: hm, well that works fine for me, enabling the Skim preferences in the same dialog as mentioned before and leaving the Typeset&View command the same as the original (which is for me a quite longish ruby script). So what does your command produce?

Comment: I fixed this problem by upgrading to TM2.

Comment: Nice, haven't tried TM2 yet, still running 1.5.11

Comment: @Ronny Would you like to write an answer?

Comment: I'll take a look at that again, both for TM 1.5.11 and 2, which I am now using, too.

Comment: I have the exact same question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several steps to making sure that TextMate works well with `biber`.

1. Make sure you have the [latest version](https://www.tug.org/mactex/) of MacTeX installed.
2. Install the TextMate 2.0 alpha. [Here](http://macromates.com/download).
3. Make sure you have the LaTeX bundle enabled. In TextMate: Preferences > Bundles > Select LaTeX bundle.
4. Configure the LaTeX bundle to use Latexmk.pl, which automatically determines which backend to use for typesetting bibliographies. In TextMate: Bundles > LaTeX > Preferences. Set options as `--shell-escape` and unable "Use Latexmk.pl"
5. If at any point `biber` fails to parse your references, you need to clear the cache. The issue & solution is described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140814/biblatex-biber-fails-with-a-strange-error-about-missing-recode-data-xml-file/140815#140815). (For mac users, it is as simple as opening terminal and entering this command:

   ```
   rm -rf `biber --cache`
   ```