# Biblatex/biber fails with a strange error about missing recode_data.xml file

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, errors, compiling, biber

I'm trying to use `biblatex` and when I compile my document I get an error like the following:

**Windows**

```
data source C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\par-5061756c\
cache-890efc00b3ca6b775c7d44a325c1349fb2a3a3bd\inc\lib/Biber/LaTeX/recode_data.xml not found in .
```

**Mac**

```
data source /var/folders/v2/rld0ls7d2935gkvqv5hfr1x00000gn/T/par-616c616e/
cache-cdd483146f82a9655ce063f848d5139480fbf872/inc/lib/Biber/LaTeX/recode_data.xml not found in .
```

**Linux**

```
data source /tmp/par-6963617269756d/cache-f37ab610b7d79b2720a8ee3732849c6821705520
/inc/lib/Biber/LaTeX/recode_data.xml not found in .
```

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18868/1998

Comment: @pmav99 I'm making this a canonical question/answer that we can link to as a duplicate.

Comment: Ok, I just added the comment so that the questions appear linked.

Comment: @Joseph Wright: You mean to mark the older question as duplicate of this one? Yeah, why not? This is the correct answer to a whole series of biber related problems.

Answer (score 241, accepted):

The error you are getting is a well known issue with `biber` that exists in versions prior to v. 2.2. For a long term solution to the problem, you should update your TeX distribution and make sure you have the latest version of `biber`.

But it's easy solve the problem right away, without updating immediately.

Biber creates binaries in a cache folder, and sometimes that can get corrupted.  In order to solve the problem, you need to manually delete the cache folders.  The name of the cache folder will be something like the following:

- `par-<hex_encoded_username>/cache-*`
- `par-<hex_encoded_username>\cache-*`

for Linux/OS and Windows respectively.  They are located in different places on different platforms:

- `/var/folders/*/*/*/` (OSX, local GUI login shell)
- `/var/tmp/` (OSX (remote ssh login shell), Unix)
- `/tmp/` (Linux)
- `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Temp` (Windows XP/Cyg-
  win)
- `C:\Windows\Temp` (Windows)
- `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp` (Windows 7/8)

You need to delete the relevant cache folders and compile your document again. You can find the location of the cache folder by looking at the `.blg` file, or by using the command.

```
biber --cache
```

On Linux and Mac, this can be combined to delete the offending folder in one command:

```
rm -rf `biber --cache`
```

More information can be found on section 4.1 of the biber manual (Section 4.1 Binary Caches).

Comment: You may add that the information about the location of the faulty cache can also be found in the `.blg` file.

Comment: And it can be found by simply looking at the error message:  `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\par-5061756c\`

Comment: I solve this problem in *NIX systems (linux and MacOX) on the command line with `rm -Rf "biber --cache"` (sorry, I do not know how to markdown backquotes, so I used `"` insted). Maybe you want to incorporate this into your answer.

Comment: This is great. Does anybody now if this has been reported to the package maintainers? I know I've been getting this bug for well over a year and I'm still getting this on biber v. 1.8.

Comment: I am looking into this again and it seems that it is probably related to windows automatic cleanup of Temp data dirs. The problem is that it cleans up things that are not locked and then when you run the next time, the cache unpacking happens again automatically for missing items - *however* - special files like the recode XML are not unpacked auutomatically again, hence the error. The workaround is still to delete and re-create the cache but I'm looking into potential other workarounds.

Comment: It's unbelievable that this is still a problem in `biber 1.9` – one that I encountered twice in the last month without doing any modifications. Since every minor release seems to be taking about a year, I don't expect it to be fixed any soon… `:-(`

Comment: @PLK: this is not just a Windows issue. My OS X install has had this problem for years and I still encounter it once a week or so.

Comment: Actually, this is now actively being addressed by the relevant module (PAR::Packer) developers and there is a beta fix out at the moment and so I hope to be able to update biber with this fix soon.

Comment: Making `biber` work saved me from finding out, why `BibLaTex` would not sort my entries with `backend=bibtex` and `sorting=nty`.

Comment: I defined a bash alias for `rm -rf \`biber --cache\` *.aux *.bcf *.bbl` because of this bug...

Comment: This bug is still an ongoing problem that is making biblatex a real pain.

Comment: To reiterate, this is a problem with certain OSes which clean up tmp directories automatically. It is a known issue wth the Par::Packer perl module and is being actively addressed by the maintainer and I think there will be a fix released soon. When this has been released, I will make a new biber release with the updated module. I think this should fix  this problem for good.

Comment: The PAR module which biber uses to unpack has just been updated with a fix for this issue. I am in the process of upgrading the build farms to use this and will release biber 2.2 DEV soon with this fix incorporated.

Comment: I don't think anyone should use `rm -rf \`biber --cache\``, at least not without checking what the output of `biber --cache` is. In my case, this is _No cache - you are not running the PAR::Packer executable version of biber_, and god knows what might happen when one tries running `rm -rf` on this.

Comment: For fish shell you need to run `rm -rf (biber --cache)`

Comment: In my case `biber --cache` didn't work, because it turned out I had something else installed with home-brew that was called biber (some cryptography package). Once I removed the other package, this command worked and it fixed my issue

Answer (score 10):

Biber 2.2 DEV is now updated on SourceForge with an updated PAR::Packer module which is supposed to fix this. Now, `biber` should be able to unpack itself properly again after any OS tmp cache cleanup.

Comment: Thanks Philip. This is really good news. When will the new version appear on CTAN (and therefore be included in the regular update process)?  Perhaps I can then just update my answer when this is done. Until then, this answer is a bit premature, since I don't think it's a good idea for people to be downloading their own version of `biber` outside of the regular update mechanism.

Comment: I'd like a few people to try this version first and see if the problem recurs first.

Comment: biber 2.2 has just been released and will make its way into TexLive soon.

Comment: Great. Thanks Philip. I've been using the pre-release version and the error has certainly disappeared.  I'll update the answer to reflect the new release.