# biber doesn't seem to be working after upgrade to Windows 8.1

Tags: texmaker, biber

My minimal example:

`.bib` file:

```
@article{hope_policy_1993,
    title = {Policy analysis of the greenhouse effect: An application of the {PAGE} model},
    volume = {21},
    issn = {0301-4215},
    shorttitle = {Policy analysis of the greenhouse effect},
    url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030142159390253C},
    doi = {10.1016/0301-4215(93)90253-C},
    number = {3},
    urldate = {2013-12-19},
    journal = {Energy Policy},
    author = {Hope, Chris and Anderson, John and Wenman, Paul},
    month = mar,
    year = {1993},
    keywords = {Greenhouse effect, Modelling, Uncertainty},
    pages = {327--338}
}
```

And my `.tex` file that works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biberEx.bib}

\begin{document}
Citation test: \cite{hope_policy_1993}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I am using Texmaker and run `pdflatex + bibtex8 + pdflatex + pdflatex` and it works fine.

When I change the `.tex` file to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biberEx.bib}

\begin{document}
Citation test biber: \cite{hope_policy_1993}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and run `pdflatex + biber + pdflatex + pdflatex`,

I get a pdf compiled that reads: "Citation test biber [hope˙policy˙1993 ]". The warning messages I get in Texmaker are: "Citation 'hope_policy_1993' on page 1 undefined" and "There were undefined references".

It seems like maybe biber can't see/read my .bib file. Any ideas? Any help would be much appreciated, as well as feedback on my question asking as this is my first `tex.stackexchange` post.

Also note I have just upgraded to Windows 8.1 from Windows 8 and everything seemed to work fine on the old OS. I have reinstalled MiKTeX, Texmaker, and biber to no avail.

Comment: If you run `biber` for the very first time, this might be connected to a well-known cache problem for biber. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140814/biblatex-biber-fails-with-a-strange-error-about-missing-recode-data-xml-file and especially the answer by Alan Munn. I run your code and got the reference correctly!

Comment: @christianhupfer, thanks so much for the very quick reply. I have worked out the problem - I was using the wrong version of biber. I replaced it with the version [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/biber/binaries/Windows).

Comment: You could answer your question yourself and earn the `self-learner - badge` (possibly ;-))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have worked out the problem - I was using the wrong version of biber. I replaced it with the version at http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/biber/binaries/Windows.