# Biber Problem in OSX: why references not compiled?

Tags: biblatex, biber, mactex, mac

**[Update]** *This is solved thanks to Adam Liter's contribution in chat. This is summarised to a community answer below.*

I cannot understand why the references do not get compiled. I am running Yosemite 10.10 and newest `MacTeX`. They got compiled in another document a few days ago. We are having a discussion about this bug in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18644942#18644942) -- welcome to join us!

**Why are the references not getting compiled?**

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt,english]{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{henrisReferences.bib}
\begin{document}

\section{Problem Statament \cite{problemStatement}}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**henrisReferences.bib**

```
@webpage{problemStatement,
    Date-Added = {2014-11-17 15:45:23 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-11-17 15:46:00 +0000},
    Lastchecked = {17th November 2014},
    Url = {http://www.ipt.ntnu.no/~kleppe/TPG4150/2014.pdf}}
```

Comment: Given the lack of the MWE in what you provided, 3 questions. First, why are you hard-coding the numbered items in the References block? Second, what type of citation were you expecting in the `\cite{groupWork}` command? Third, any reason why the `groupWork` bibliography entry has no author or title? If the default citation style expects either, there could be a problem.

Comment: Why `\addbibliographysource`? (I've never seen this before.) Sorry, but I am not downloading a random DropBox file just to answer a question. If you don't have time to create an MWe, you don't have time to ask the question. But you could at least post it as a text file somewhere it can be viewed.

Comment: @cfr what would you use instead?

Comment: ***I*** would use `\bibliography...`. But the recommendation is to use `\addbibresource...`.

Comment: @cfr dyxlexia: I actually have `\addbibresource` X(

Comment: The bold groupWork is a cite command which hasn't been resolved yet - either because you didn't run biber, or because biber gave an error or because the bib entry is not in the bib-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you, I added a simple MWE to make it easier to understand the question -- I just cannot spot the error :(

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been solved by updating the TeX packages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### **Update3: keep the MacTeX automatically updated**

---

```
sudo su
tlmgr update --self --all
```

### **Update 2:** removing the cache of `biber` solved the reoccurring problem

---

The `biber` problem reoccurred and [egreg](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19661780#19661780) directed to the solution [Biblatex/biber fails with a strange error about missing recode_data.xml file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140814/biblatex-biber-fails-with-a-strange-error-about-missing-recode-data-xml-file) so

> ```
> rm -rf `biber --cache`
> ```

---

### **Update 1:** updating MacTex solved the problem

---

This was an OSX related thing: I had `biber` 1.8 and after updating the whole TeX Live with `"Tex Live Utility"` things started to work. It was not enough to update to the newest MacTeX! You have to also update things with the Graphical tool in OSX!

[image]

I thank [Adam Liter](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18646202#18646202) for finding the solution in the chat:

> *I'm on a Mac right now, and I get the same error you see in System Preferences. However, I haven't had any problems updating my TeX
>   distro with TeX Live Utility. If you just search TeX Live Utility in
>   Spotlight, you should see it come up. After you open it, it will allow
>   you to update all of your packages.*

Comment: `rm -rf \`biber --cache\`` worked for me!