# How can I create bibliographies after each section?

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing

I am writing a document that in a way consists of many different papers. People reading the document may be interested only in a small aspect of it. I want to make it easier to read for different people by breaking up the bibliography after each section.

**"How can I create bibliographies after each section?"** and its **Helper questions**

> 1. How can I show bibliographies after each section or a specific point related to the earlier section?
> 2. How does your method work if some references are common between the sections?

Comment: Have you looked into the [chapterbib](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cite) package?

Comment: @Mico Thank you for the information. I have never heard about it. I will wait to see other choices. Or are there other choices and their pros and cons?

Comment: The `biblatex` package also allows for this with a great deal of flexibility.

Comment: I'm currently doing precisely this with `biblatex` and `biber`. It is much more automatic than `chapterbib` and `bibtex`. (You don't have to run the backend once per bibliography - you just run it on the main file as usual.)

Comment: Same opinion as @cfr: `biblatex` defines the `refsection` and `refsegment` environment. You also can print bibliography organised by categories.

Comment: The answer to your second question (which you call your first) is that it depends... It depends how you configure it, which options you choose... The way I do it, a reference which occurs in multiple reference sections will be listed in the list of references in each of those sections. But you can use categories, as Bernard says, or other means of filtering, if that's what you want.

Comment: @cfr is it possible to provide a SWE? I am currently using biber so particularly interested in your alternative.

Comment: @hhh Can you provide an MWE with your current `biblatex` set-up, some demo `.bib` entries and a couple of chapters/sections or whatever? Also, can you say how you want to handle the case of a reference in multiple chapters/sections? It's really hard to provide a useful MWE in the answer when there isn't one in the question!

Comment: @cfr I posted a picture in this question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233266/how-to-beautify-files-related-to-latex-document-for-arxiv-publication), I try to get my LaTex working directory beautified to ArXiv so it could be easier to work on this -- taking some time. I am not yet sure what is the best way to work with document compiled with LaTex: I use a lot of directories to keep order and one main LaTex file that sources relevant documents.

Comment: An MWE. Not a picture.

Comment: @cfr https://www.dropbox.com/s/g62kq6xih5c4iod/20150315_Test_Biber_many_references.zip?dl=0 where I created 3 separate bib files and after each section I want the references related to them printed, I have apparently [this biber prob](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212540/biber-problem-in-osx-why-references-not-compiled) re-emerging -- can you get it compiled in your comp?

Comment: @cfr pastebin version about the MWE [here](http://pastebin.com/0u12jRXA) where a.bib, b.bib, c.bib and test.txt stdouted.

Comment: How to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). How to create a [minimum working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography). It isn't generally useful to post stuff elsewhere as your question will not help future users if the links disappear or the contents changes. In any case, creating a suitable example usually helps you to diagnose (sometimes even solve) the problem yourself.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just search the site - there are questions about this already. (Some are listed on the right.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't want that the comments disappear so summarising the Biber solution so far here, hopefully someone can clarify this with SWE so easy to use this method.

**Biber**

**Timeline in comments**

> Cfr mentioned
>
> > I'm currently doing precisely this with biblatex and biber. It is much
> >     more automatic than chapterbib and bibtex. (You don't have to run the
> >     backend once per bibliography - you just run it on the main file as
> >     usual.)
>
> while Bernard mentioned
>
> > Same opinion as @cfr: biblatex defines the refsection and refsegment
> >     environment. You also can print bibliography organised by categories.
>
> so there looks to be some easy solution with Biber.