# How to clean up files related to LaTeX document for ArXiv publication?

Tags: arxiv, publishing

My directory looks like this

[image]

where I have many bibliographies sourced, many third-party documents related to the publication, scripts and main LaTex file sources the chapters from the Chapters folder. In order to submit my paper to [ArXiv](https://arxiv.org/help/submit), how can I beautify - clean up - a LaTeX document and its related parts in order to be accepted to ArXiv?

Comment: What exactly is you definiton of *beautifying something*?

Comment: I'm with @Johannes_B on this thing. Before you posted the answer, I had a feeling that "I don't understand what this is about, let see what happens next". But now, I'm convinced that this is a purely unclear question, and that you are actually not in the need to ask it.

Comment: @yo' It has the charackter of some kind of question that one can easily refer to. archive like.

Comment: Character maybe, but it's unclear what the goal is as of now, and I doubt it's googlable, with "beautify" used in a strange meaning, and with one large picture instead of anything useful.

Comment: hhh, you see, a bit of clarification might be useful here.

Answer (score 3):

You can provide a Zip or Tar file about your working directory, instructions [here](http://arxiv.org/help/tar). Beautifying means to delete all extraneous material

> *"**it is important that you do not include extraneous files**, leftover files, backup files, anything which does not belong to the paper you are submitting or is not needed for processing. Do not include journal templates, referee letters, or man pages. Tidy your submission before you pack it up."* [Source](https://arxiv.org/help/submit_tex).

and

> *"Your (La)TeX, AMS(La)TeX, or PDFLaTeX submission will be processed automatically by our AutoTeX software."*

and check up the version ArXiv uses for TexLive: as of 2015, they mention TexLive 2011 [here](https://arxiv.org/help/faq/mistakes) -- this may cause problems in getting Biber for example running like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212540/biber-problem-in-osx-why-references-not-compiled) so test it with TexLive 2011 and/or check their supporeted TexLive version.

**Other tips**

> 1. *"We strongly encourage you to **include archive/papernum identifiers** in your reference list for both published and unpublished papers"*
> 2. *"Do not include extraneous font commands, spaces, tildes, braces or line-breaks within the e-print identifier"*
> 3. *"If your submission includes any plain text files which should not be processed (e.g. Fortran source code, data files), then make the first line of those files **%auto-ignore** This ensures that they will be ignored by the auto-postscript generator."*