# Problem with Biber citation

Tags: biber

I have used biber succesfully, but now I have ran into a problem. My pdf files look like this: This citation is not working (**eco_theory_1979**). 
When I typeset this tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{norsk}{norsk-apa}
%\addbibresource{test.bib}
\bibliography{test}

\begin{document} 
This citation is not working \parencite{eco_theory_1979}. 
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Here is the bib file

```
@book{eco_theory_1979,
    Address = {Bloomington, {IN}},
    Author = {Eco, Umberto},
    Date-Added = {2014-07-28 17:35:21 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-07-28 17:35:21 +0000},
    Isbn = {0253202175, 9780253202178},
    Publisher = {Indiana University Press},
    Title = {A theory of semiotics},
    Year = {1979}}
```

This is what the log file reports:

```
No file test.bbl.
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'eco_theory_1979' on page 1 undefined on input line 13.
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 15.
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                test
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

Previously I have compiled similar files without problems. There seem to be a problem that no bbl file is created. I am using TexPad on a Mac and have tried to compile in several ways (autodetect, bibtex...)
I will be very happy if anyone can help

Comment: [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751)

Comment: Btw: There is no `cite` in your example. `\begin{document}` is missing as well. Having added that, the example runs just fine.

Comment: What is the content of the .blg-file?

Comment: It might be that the biber cache is corrupted.

Comment: Sorry! Here is the correct tex example:\begin{document}

This citation is not working \parencite{eco_theory_1979}. 

\printbibliography
\end{document}

Comment: Here is the content of the .blg file: [0] 73b5ab1d.pm:320> INFO - This is Biber 1.9
[0] 73b5ab1d.pm:323> INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg'

Comment: If it is an issue with the cache, as Guido suggested above, this answer will help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140814/biblatex-biber-fails-with-a-strange-error-about-missing-recode-data-xml-file

Comment: I runned your MWE using TeXstudio on Windows 7 and all worked fine. I used the sequence: `XeLaTeX -> Biber -> XeLaTeX`

Comment: As you can see, code markup in comments is terrible. You can edit that information into the question where it gets seen by helpers more easily.

Comment: It was an issue with the cache!! I deleted the files and now everything is fine. Thanks a million times!

Comment: The same here. My laptop did not create bbl files anymore. After clearing up the cache everything's fine again.

Comment: I'm voting to close as a duplicate, see comments above.