# biber stopped working?

Tags: biber, texstudio, mac

Got on today to add a citation to a document that I last edited on Friday (2 days ago).

Now I am getting this message when I run "Bibliography" (from within TeXstudio) "No such file or directory at'' yada yada yada -- the file name is way too long to reproduce here.

What initially happened was that the new citation I included in an old file was not being written, rather the "Cite Key" label that I typed into the parencite command appeared. When I deleted all of the LaTeX files except the .tex file (fresh start and all of that!) ALL of my citations now became simply the BibTeX Cite Key labels.

I then went to an older file (one that was working fine last Wednesday), deleted all LaTeX files except the .tex one, and ran everything "as I usually would". The result is that ALL of the citations in that file now appear as their BibTex Cite Key labels.

Note that I did NOTHING to this "old" (last Wednesday's) .tex file. I just deleted its LaTeX friends and then redid everything that I have done 1001 times since installing TeXstudio.

My configuration is Mac 10.10.1; TeXstudio 2.8.8. I updated all files (after this started to happen) using TeX Live Utility today. All of this did nothing.

NOW --- and maybe this is the clue -- I did run the latest Mac updates of Safari; OS X Update to 10.10.1 and Command Line Tools (OS X 10.10) version 6.1 earlier today.

Any hints? Anything else I should include from my Installation info?

*** Okay -- I am being told that my question is redundant. Actually the answer is redundant, not the question. The two questions differ but the diagnosis is the same. However, my extensive search (prior to posting my question) did not reveal the older answer. I suggest the question be left so that someone who diagnoses their problem the way I diagnosed mine will be lead to the answer.

Comment: Did you actually run `biber` (or `BiBTeX`)?

Comment: The key line is: ``\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}'' that has not changed for about 2-3 years.

Comment: Of course that line is necessary, but have you actually executed `biber`? Otherwise, no bibliography will be generated.

Comment: It looks like the `biber` cache is corrupted and `biber` did not run.  Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140815/16895

Comment: This worked! Specifically, typing `$ rm -rf 'biber --cache'` worked. @Guido @Gonzalo

Comment: @Wayne: With an upvoted post, this will remain for future visitors to find, at which time they'll identify the mentioned source-duplicate.