# Biber 1.9, working with Biblatex 2.9a on Yosemite, suddenly not producing .bbl file

Tags: biblatex, biber, mactex

Out of the blue, I'm getting this error for all my .tex files with citations (even those which ran smoothly just a couple of days ago). I typeset them on another MacBook with the same distribution and all updates and they work just fine. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling my TeX Distribution but I keep getting the same error.

```
INFO - This is Biber 1.9
INFO - Logfile is 'siÌlabo_lyta_1.blg'
read_file '/var/folders/g9/qcll94p57w985k2gtngk3dcr0000gn/T/par-687966616e7465/cache-a3cdad92316c60c9c5179d80d6bb51a7a024393c//inc/lib/Biber/LaTeX/recode_data.xml' - sysopen: No such file or directory at /var/folders/g9/qcll94p57w985k2gtngk3dcr0000gn/T/par-687966616e7465/cache-a3cdad92316c60c9c5179d80d6bb51a7a024393c/bda77484.pm line 112.
Latexmk: Failed to find one or more biber source files:
  NONE
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  biber sílabo_lyta_1: Could not find all biber source files for 'sílabo_lyta_1'
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Did you try deleting all the .aux, .bbl, .blg, etc (all the files except the tex)?

Comment: Have you tried removing the folder `var/folders/g9/qcll94p57w985k2gtngk3dcr0000gn/T/par-687966616e7465/`?

Comment: Didn't work, but it definitively had to with that! I found this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140814/biblatex-biber-fails-with-a-strange-error-about-missing-recode-data-xml-file. So, it's a matter of the Biber cache folders getting corrupted. I deleted them using "rm -rf `biber --cache`" and that worked like a charm.