# biber producing weird error

Tags: biber

When running biber I get this error. Anybody knows what causes this?

```
INFO - This is Biber 1.9
INFO - Logfile is 'root.tex.blg'
read_file '/var/folders/6_/m4ps2q251c971g6s42g04j9h0000gn/T/par-727564666164656e/cache-a3cdad92316c60c9c5179d80d6bb51a7a024393c//inc/lib/Biber/LaTeX/recode_data.xml' - sysopen: No such file or directory at /var/folders/6_/m4ps2q251c971g6s42g04j9h0000gn/T/par-727564666164656e/cache-a3cdad92316c60c9c5179d80d6bb51a7a024393c/bda77484.pm line 112.
```

Comment: delete the cache-folder mentioned in the error message.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140814/biblatex-biber-fails-with-a-strange-error-about-missing-recode-data-xml-file