# Recent alternatives to the historian package

Tags: biblatex

The historian reference style is almost exactly what I need, but it's causing a lot of errors and seems to be kind of outdated. Are there any recommended recent alternatives?

I need footnote references containing:

- for books: initial, the author's last name in small caps, italic title, place, year, page.
- for articles: initial, the author's last name in small caps, 'article title', italic journal title (edition, year), page.
- for ancient texts: the abbreviations of Thesaurus Lingua Latina & Liddell-Scott-Jones

Comment: Mhh, how far do you get with the standard `verbose`/`verbose-ibid`/`verbose-inote` styles? What you now seem to want is quite easy to modify from these, I imagine. But I suspect there might be some more rules you need/want to follow. For a starter on how to modify a style see [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864).

Comment: The documentation of `biblatex-historian` says it follows Turabian which in turn is based on Chicago, so you might want to try [`biblatex-chicago`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chicago) which is under active development. Keep in mind though that it is often easier to modify standard styles then heavily-tailored styles such as CMS.

Comment: I just had another look at the styles, probably `verbose-inote` comes closest to `biblatex-historian`. In order to get small caps, you will want `\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}`. The rest seems to almost be in order (maybe [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864) is missing).

Comment: Thanks. Where can I find the verbose-inote style?

Comment: `verbose-inote` is a standard style that comes with `biblatex`, so `style=verbose-inote` as option should suffice (as in `\usepackage[style=verbose-inote,backend=biber]{biblatex}`).

Comment: Thanks again! I'm getting this "data source /var/folders/tf/8bm5xl0d0hj30x0c2t95_h7c0000gn/T/par-6c6f7265676f657468616c73/cache-1ea1c894d061cba85b64a1b380f6c297de02c7c4//inc/lib/Biber/LaTeX/recode_data.xml not found in .
INFO - This is Biber 1.8
INFO - Logfile is 'thesis.blg'" error when I try to compile it to biblatex. Can I put a MWE somewhere over here or do have to start a new topic for that?

Comment: Try [Biblatex/biber fails with a strange error about missing recode_data.xml file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864) first. (Also Biber 1.8 is not the newest version, there already is 1.9; more important than being up-to-date though is that `biblatex` and Biber match in their versions: see table 1 on page 6 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf))

Comment: Updating Biber made it work! Time to figure out how to change the style now. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: @moewe I added some references in the meantime, but they didn't show up. After compiling the whole thing a few times and installing biber again, all my references are gone now and nothing seems to help getting them back. I want to clear my cache with rm -rf `biber --cache` but actually have no idea where on my mac I have to write this command. Posting this here since I'm too newbie to be allowed to comment in the biblatex topic mentioned above.

Comment: You will have to issue rm -rf `biber --cache` in the Terminal (command line) [see here how to find it](http://www.davidbaumgold.com/tutorials/command-line/). But this really only helps if you get an obscure error along the lines of `recode_data.xml not found`.

Comment: @moewe It doesn't help. The error I get is - sysopen: No such file or directory at /var/folders/tf/8bm5xl0d0hj30x0c2t95_h7c0000gn/T/par-6c6f7265676f657468616c73/cache-a3cdad92316c60c9c5179d80d6bb51a7a024393c/bda77484.pm line 112.

Comment: Thatr very much looks like an error that could be solved by deleting the cache though. Maybe you have multiple instances on your system now. Try the manual solution outlined [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864) and make sure you get all of those `par-...` folders.

Comment: For the abbreviations, you'll have to add those in yourself. The `shorthand` field might be the way to go.

Answer (score 24):

Unfortunately, [`biblatex-historian`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-historian) has last been updated in 2010 and does not seem to be actively maintained any more. `biblatex` has progressed quite a bit in the last five years and so getting `biblatex-historian` to work without rough edges becomes increasingly complicated.

In `biblatex` version 3.3, the name formatting has been revised quite substantially (see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/372, [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864)), so many styles released before March 2016 will have problems with newer `biblatex` versions. Depending on the commands used this can cause `biblatex` to silently ignore certain modifications, issue harmless warnings or fatal errors.

The [`biblatex-philosophy`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-philosophy) style family is very actively maintained (version 1.9 is dated `2016-11-26`) and its `philosophy-verbose` style allows for footnote citations. This style family implements many additional options for a finer and more comfortable control over lots of features.

As an alternative you can use [`biblatex-chicago`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chicago) (version 1.0rc1 is from 2016-06-07). Turabian style, which is what `biblatex-historian` implements, and the Chicago Manual of Style are closely related and differ only in details. There are going to be subtle differences though, and since `biblatex-chicago` is purpose-built to follow the CMS it might not to be too easy to get the exact output of `biblatex-historian`. See an example of [the `chicago-note` style here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/examples/cms-notes-sample.pdf).

Another style for the humanities is [`biblatex-dw`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-dw). It has been updated to version 1.7 recently (2016-12-06) and now works with the current versions of `biblatex`. You can see [an example of the `footnote-dw` style here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-dw/doc/examples/en-footnote-dw.pdf).

Finally there are `biblatex`'s standard styles, footnote styles are called `verbose-...`. The style [`verbose-inote`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/73-style-verbose-inote.pdf) as well as the [`verbose-trad1`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/74-style-verbose-trad1.pdf), [`verbose-trad2`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/75-style-verbose-trad2.pdf) and [`verbose-trad3`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/76-style-verbose-trad3.pdf) styles could fit the bill. Using the standard styles offers the advantage of easy customisability, they are also guaranteed to keep up with `biblatex`'s development.

Comment: +1, `biblatex-dw` has been a good choice for me, easy to customize, at least to a certain degree.

Answer (score 5):

Since the question is also about ancient texts and their abbreviations I can recommend a `biblatex`-style which is called

## archaeologie

- [documentation](http://pdf.biblatex-archaeologie.de);
- [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/archaeologie);
- [website](http://www.biblatex-archaeologie.de);
- [github](https://github.com/LukasCBossert/biblatex-archaeologie).

However the style covers rules of the **[German Archaeological Institute (Deutsches Archäologisches Institut)](https://www.dainst.de)** in first place there are many options to adjust the outcome to ones preferences.

Furthermore the style is fully implemented within **German, English, French, Italian and Spanish language**.

### Options for the preamble are regarding

#### *  additional bibliographies

- `bibancient` (bibliography-file with ancient authors and work),
- `bibcorpora` (bibliography-file with corpora),
- `lstabbrv` (list of abbreviations for `journaltitle` and `series` [`@String`]),
- `lstlocations` (list of abbreviations for `location` [`@String`]),
- `lstpublishers` (list of abbreviations for `publisher` [`@String`]),

#### * notation of names

- `bibfullname`(full name in bibliography),
- `citeauthorformat` (citationformat within text),
- `initials` (show digraphs/trigraphs of initials),
- `scshape` (print authos with scmall capitals).

#### * manner of citing

- `edby` (change editor-format),
- `inreferences` (different citing for `@inreferences`),
- `noabbrv` (show long forms of `journaltitle`/ `series`),
- `publisher` (print publishers),
- `seenote` (different citation-system [see note XY]),
- `translation` (show translated titles),
- `yearinparens` (put year of publication within parentheses),
- `yearseries` (switch order of `year` and `series`).

  - global bibliography settings (adjust the width of label and full-citation, count the appearence of a work in the text)

#### Options for entries `options = {}`

- `ancient` (entry is ancient source)
  [image]
  [image]
- `frgancient` (entry is a fragmentary ancient source)
  [image]
- `corpus` (entry will be cited with its `shorthand`)
  [image]
- `uniqueme` (in cases of several works of the same ancient author)
  [image]

### Entries

#### `@article`

[image]

#### `@book`/`@collection`

[image]
[image]
[image]

#### `@inbook`/ `@incollection`

[image]

#### `@review`

[image]
[image]
[image]

#### `@proceedings` and `@inproceedings`

[image]

#### `@phdthesis`

[image]