# MacTex 2016 Math Mode Errors

Tags: math-mode, biblatex, errors, pdftex, mactex

Hi I just installed MacTex 2016 and suddenly Latex shows a lot of errors when compiling (I am using pdflatex).

The errors that I get look like this:

> Latex Error: ./untitled.tex:429 Missing $ inserted.
>
> Latex Error: ./untitled.tex:429 You can't use `\spacefactor' in math mode.
>
> Latex Error: ./untitled.tex:429 You can't use `\spacefactor' in math mode.
>
> Latex Error: ./untitled.tex:429 You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode.

and this is MWE where I also get these errors:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
     citecolor=black,
     filecolor=black,
     linkcolor=black,
     urlcolor=black
}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{footnote}{section}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@incollection{athanasius1998,
    Address = {Berlin/New York},
    Author = {{Athanasius Alexandrinus}},
    Booktitle = {Athanasius Werke - Die dogmatischen Schriften},
    Call-Number = {TH: Vb 17.02-1.1.2},
    Date-Added = {2010-10-16 13:24:30 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-13 17:12:32 +0000},
    Editor = {Marin Tetz and others},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {109-175},
    Publisher = {Walter de Gruyter},
    Read = {No},
    Series = {Urkunden zur Geschichte des Arianischen Streites 318-328},
    Shortauthor = {Ath.},
    Shorttitle = {Ar. 1},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Title = {Oratio I contra Arianos},
    Volume = {1, Tl. 1, Lfg. 2},
    Year = {1998}}
@incollection{evagrius2011,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Evagrius Scholasticus}},
    Booktitle = {{\'E}vagre Le Scholastique: Histoire Eccl{\'e}siastique - Livres I-III},
    Call-Number = {TH: Va1.05/542},
    Date-Added = {2013-08-24 12:11:20 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:54:31 +0000},
    Editor = {Joseph Bidez and Leon Parmentier},
    Keywords = {source},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {Evagr.},
    Shorttitle = {h.e.},
    Title = {Historia ecclesiastica},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {542},
    Year = {2011}}
@incollection{gregoire1978,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 27-31},
    Call-Number = {TH: Va 1.05 250},
    Date-Added = {2011-08-29 09:18:38 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2014-05-29 10:45:06 +0000},
    Editor = {Paul Gallay},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {226-275},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 30},
    Title = {Oratio 30: De Filio (Theologica Quatra)},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {250},
    Year = {1978}}
@incollection{gregoire1974,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Lettres th{\'e}ologiques},
    Call-Number = {TH: Va 1.05 208},
    Date-Added = {2010-04-22 16:22:42 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:54:28 +0000},
    Editor = {Paul Gallay},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {87-95},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {ep. 202},
    Title = {Epistula 202: Ad Nectarium Constantinopolitanum},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {208},
    Year = {1974}}
@incollection{gregorius1981,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 24-26},
    Date-Added = {2014-05-29 12:04:21 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-05-29 12:05:35 +0000},
    Editor = {Justin Mossay},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {40-85},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 24},
    Title = {Oratio 24: In laudem s. Cypriani},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {284},
    Year = {1980}}
@incollection{gregorius1990,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 38-41},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-27 09:58:33 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:53:58 +0000},
    Editor = {Claudio Moreschini},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {104-148},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 38},
    Title = {Oratio 38: In Theophania},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {358},
    Year = {1990}}
@incollection{gregorius1979/1,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 27-31},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-27 09:54:29 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 18:41:48 +0000},
    Editor = {Paul Gallay},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {176-225},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 29},
    Title = {Oratio 29: Theologica III},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {250},
    Year = {1979}}

@incollection{gregoire1978/2,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 27-31},
    Call-Number = {TH: Va 1.05 250},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-26 18:56:20 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:54:18 +0000},
    Editor = {Paul Gallay},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {276-343},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 31},
    Title = {Oratio 31: Theologica V},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {250},
    Year = {1978}}

@incollection{gregorius1978,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 1-3},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-26 18:48:54 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 18:42:08 +0000},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {84-241},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 2},
    Title = {Oratio 2: Apologetica},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {247},
    Year = {1978}}

@incollection{gregorius1990/2,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 38-41},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-26 17:58:16 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:53:48 +0000},
    Editor = {Claudio Moreschini},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {150-197},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 39},
    Title = {Oratio 39: In sancta lumina},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {358},
    Year = {1990}}

@incollection{gregorius1992,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 42-43},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-26 17:58:15 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:53:44 +0000},
    Editor = {Jean Bernardi},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {48-115},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 42},
    Title = {Oratio 42: Supremum vale},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {384},
    Year = {1992}}

@incollection{gregorius1990/1,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 38-41},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-26 17:58:15 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 18:41:25 +0000},
    Editor = {Claudio Moreschini},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {198-311},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 40},
    Title = {Oratio 40: In sanctum baptisma},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {358},
    Year = {1990}}

@incollection{gregorius1980/1,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 20-23},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-26 17:42:35 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:54:01 +0000},
    Editor = {Justin Mossay},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {220-258},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 22},
    Title = {Oratio 22: De pace II},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {270},
    Year = {1980}}

@incollection{gregorius1978/1,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 1-3},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-26 17:42:34 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 18:41:59 +0000},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {241-255},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 3},
    Title = {Oratio 3: Ad eos qui ipsum acciverant nec occurrerant},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {247},
    Year = {1978}}

@book{moreschini1997,
    Address = {Oxford},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Call-Number = {Googlebooks},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-26 15:07:53 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-26 15:14:45 +0000},
    Editor = {Claudio Moreschini and},
    Keywords = {source},
    Publisher = {Clarendon Press},
    Series = {Oxford Theological Monographs},
    Title = {St. Gregory of Nazianzus: \textit{Poemata Arcana}},
    Translator = {Donald Sykes},
    Year = {1997}}

@book{white1996,
    Address = {Cambridge},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Call-Number = {Googlebooks},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-26 15:05:53 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-26 15:07:22 +0000},
    Editor = {Carolinne White},
    Keywords = {source},
    Publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
    Title = {Gregory of Nazianzus: Autobiographical Poems},
    Translator = {Carolline White},
    Year = {1996}}
@book{gregorius1862,
    Address = {Parisiis},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Call-Number = {PDF},
    Date-Added = {2014-03-15 15:58:32 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-31 08:01:30 +0000},
    Editor = {Jacques Paul Migne},
    Keywords = {source},
    Publisher = {Accurante J.-P. Migne},
    Series = {Patrologiae cursus completus: Series Graeca},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {hym. 30},
    Title = {Hymnus 30: Ad Deum},
    Usera = {PG},
    Volume = {37},
    Year = {1862}}
@incollection{gregorius1980,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Discours 20-23},
    Date-Added = {2013-04-25 14:10:40 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:54:04 +0000},
    Editor = {Justin Mossay},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {110-193},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {or. 21},
    Title = {Oratio 21: In laudem Athanasii},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {270},
    Year = {1980}}
@incollection{gregoire1974/2,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Gregorius Nazianzenus}},
    Booktitle = {Lettres th{\'e}ologiques},
    Call-Number = {TH: Va 1.05 208},
    Date-Added = {2012-05-04 16:46:23 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:54:26 +0000},
    Editor = {Paul Gallay},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {37-69},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {{Gr. Naz.}},
    Shorttitle = {ep. 101},
    Title = {Epistula 101: Ad Cledonium presbyterum contra Apollinarium},
    Usera = {SCh},
    Volume = {208},
    Year = {1974}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=historische-zeitschrift, maxnames=2, hyperref=true, backref=true, backrefstyle=none, backend=bibtex,idemtracker=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
%
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{footcite}{%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx@loccit}%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx@seenote}% NEW!
  \ifciteseen
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
          {\usebibmacro{footcite:ibid}}
          {\usebibmacro{footcite:note}}}
       {\usebibmacro{footcite:shorthand}}}
       {\iffieldundef{usera}
         {\usebibmacro{footcite:full}}{\printnames{author}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \printfield{title}\isdot%
         {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
          \usebibmacro{in:}%
          \printfield{usera}%
          \setunit*{\addspace}%
          \printfield[default]{volume}}}}%
     \usebibmacro{footcite:save}}

%

\renewbibmacro*{footcite:note}{%
  \global\booltrue{cbx@seenote}% NEW!
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\printfield{label}}
    {\printnames{labelname}}%
  \ifsingletitle
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
     \printfield[title]{labeltitle}}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%<--- CHANGED
  \printtext{%
    \bibhyperlink{\thefield{entrykey}:%
                  \@nameuse{cbx@first@\thefield{entrykey}}}{%
      \printtext{\bibleftparen}%
      \bibstring{seenote}\addnbspace
      \@nameuse{cbx@note@\thefield{entrykey}}%
      \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
      \bibstring{page}\addnbspace
      \@nameuse{cbx@page@\thefield{entrykey}}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{footcite:save}{%
  \ifundef\@thefnmark
    {\ifundef\@theenmark % endnotes.sty
       {\csgdef{cbx@note@\thefield{entrykey}}{%
          \BibliographyWarning{Missing footnote mark}\textbf{??}}}
       {\global\cslet{cbx@note@\thefield{entrykey}}\@theenmark}}
    {\global\cslet{cbx@note@\thefield{entrykey}}\@thefnmark}%
  \global\cslet{cbx@page@\thefield{entrykey}}\thepage
  \csxdef{cbx@first@\thefield{entrykey}}{\the\value{instcount}}}

% NO PAGES IN INCOLLECTION FOOTNOTES BUT PAGES IN BIBLIOGRAPHY
%
\renewbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
  \printfield{chapter}%
  \newunit}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}
     {\renewbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
  \printfield{chapter}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit}}
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 56]{athanasius1998}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 22]{evagrius2011}
\pagebreak
\section{Second section}
\blindtext\footcite[Vgl.][S. ]{gregoire1974,gregoire1974/2,gregoire1978,gregoire1978/2,gregorius1862,gregorius1978,gregorius1978/1,gregorius1979/1,gregorius1980,gregorius1980/1,gregorius1981,gregorius1990,gregorius1990/1,gregorius1990/2,gregorius1992}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 12]{evagrius2011}
\pagebreak
\section{Third section}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 11]{athanasius1998}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 12]{evagrius2011}
\pagebreak
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is my log file:

http://pastebin.com/usMDFFUB

Does someone know what the problem is?

Comment: It seems to be a problem  with the `historische-zeitschrift` biblatex style: it dates back to 2014, and `biblatex` had some important syntax changes in the last months.

Comment: Hm ok thank you for the hint! I guess I will just stick to MacTex 2015 until the author updates this style. Thank you again!

Comment: I get a completely different set of errors, probably because I have updated `biblatex` recently. Sorry, but `historische-zeitschrift` needs refurbishing for becoming again compatible with `biblatex` in its new versions.

Comment: @eklisiarh: Or you may try another style close to historische-zeitschrift style, which you might patch to obtain the desired result.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Which style would that be in your opinion?

Comment: You will at least have problems with [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864) (some of the problems might not show as real errors, but rather wrong output). You could check [Recent alternatives to the historian package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/231160/35864) for other styles in the Humanities.

Comment: I just checked the MWE. It compiles fine again with updated `historische-zeitschrift` style. The problem was certainly the 3.3 name format changes as well as some other changes.