# Adapting authoryear-dw to a specific citation and bibliography style

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-dw

I am trying to adapt the `authoryear-dw` style to the specific requirements for assignments at my university. They look like this:

Citations as Footnotes, incl. a first full and shorttitle citations, as well 
use of ibid. for recurring citations

[image: Footnote style]

The order of names is reversed and formatting is slighlty changed for the Bibliography:

[image: Bibliography Style]

I have succeeded in getting the order of the names and some of the formatting right, but I am failing at setting up the details (delimiters/punctuation). Also apparently my settings are not completely used for the first full citations (italic vs. upright text)

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,german]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{xunicode,fontspec,xltxtra} %für XeLaTeX
\usepackage{longtable,array,ragged2e, booktabs} %für Tabellen
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,idemtracker=true,firstfull=true,firstfullname=true,shorthandinbib=true,shorthandibid=true,backend=biber,citedas=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}



\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
%\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}


\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} % Titel in Bibliographie kursiv darstellen 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} 
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} 
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} 
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} 
\DeclareFieldFormat[patent]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} 
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} 
\DeclareFieldFormat[unpublished]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} 

\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}} % Titel in Zitat kursiv darstellen 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{citetitle}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{citetitle}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{citetitle}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{citetitle}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[patent]{citetitle}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{citetitle}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}} 
\DeclareFieldFormat[unpublished]{citetitle}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}

%\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{citetitle}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}



\renewcommand*{\nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\subtitlepunct}{\addperiod\space}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@book{runciman,
author={Runciman, Steven},
title={Die Eroberung von Konstantinopel 1453}, 
address={München}, 
year={1966}}

@book{habib2007female,
    title={Female homosexuality in the Middle East: histories and representations},
    shorttitle={Female homosexuality in the Middle East},
    author={Habib, Samar},
    number={13},
    year={2007},
    publisher={Routledge},
}

@article{al2012lesbian,
        title={The Lesbian Subjectivity in Contemporary Arabic Literature:‘An Absent Presence’ Disciplined by the Gaze},
        author={Al-Ghafari, Iman},
        journal={Al-Raida Journal},
        pages={6--18},
        year={2012}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Text.\footcite{runciman} More text.\footcite[36]{runciman} Even more text.\footnote{Test. \cite[48]{runciman}}. An even longer text.\footcite[35]{runciman} I see more text.\footcite{habib2007female} Another test.\footcite{al2012lesbian} And him again.\footcite{runciman}

\clearpage

Test\footcite{habib2007female}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Thanks for your time and your help :)

Comment: Please note that `biblatex-dw` hasn't been updated in quite some time, so you may well encounter some problems with `biblatex` versions >= 3.3.

Comment: I am happy to accept alternative approaches using other packages if there are any. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I will only be able to have a look next week. For alternatives, check out [Recent alternatives to the historian package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/231160/35864). But `biblatex-dw` is a heavily customised style with many great options, so don't be disappointed if none of the styles is able to match your expectations.

Comment: Herbert Voß has adapted `biblatex-dw` to work with version 3.3 of `biblatex` (http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/Bibliography/dw/). But the changes in version 3.5 could also prove problematic.

Comment: There's also my `geschichtsfrkl` style (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geschichtsfrkl) which should work with the current version of `biblatex`

Comment: Is there any chance someone can find the time to have a look at this? My deadline is approaching quickly and I haven't made any significant progress.

Comment: Can you provide a list of the specific changes you need, please? It is difficult to just look and spot what needs changing, especially since the citations and bibliography entries which you use in your example code are nothing like those shown in your target images!

Comment: Try pinging @moewe.

Comment: Sorry I haven't had much time during the last weeks. One problem for me is that `biblatex-dw` doesn't properly work out of the box any more. Furthermore it would be great if you could list all necessary changes in an easy to read format (a list, maybe?), so that we don't miss out on the details. It could be that your question is easily answered with a few lines of code, but seeing the modifications you need it might also be that the code would need to be quite a bit more complicated.