# BibLaTeX and Textmate

Tags: biblatex, biber, textmate

I can't get the BibLaTeX Package to work. When I run the 'create bibiliography'-command from TextMate I get the following error Message

```
INFO - This is Biber 1.9
Command bibtex exited with status 2
```

The Produced PDF-Document contains only

```
[wikipedia ]
```

but no bibliography.

The log of the pdftex doesn't show any useful information on this error

```
Document Class: scrbook 2015/02/07 v3.16 KOMA-Script document class (book)

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'wikipedia' on page 1 undefined on input line 8.
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 9.
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

Output written on Minimalbeispiel.pdf (1 page, 18613 bytes).
```

a Minimalexample which produces this error is

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{wikipedia}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

and the library.bib-Entry is

```
@misc{wikipedia,
    Author = {Wikipedia},
    Note = {[Online; accessed 24-March-2015]},
    Title = {Porosity --- Wikipedia{,} The Free Encyclopedia},
    Url = {http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Porosity&oldid=651280533},
    Year = {2015},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Porosity&oldid=651280533}
}
```

I have already used several hours searing the Web for help but couldn't find anything helpful.

I'm using TextMate version 2.0-beta.6.8 and the MacTeX-2014 Bundle

Greetings and thanks for any Help

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What is written in the .blg file?

Comment: Thanks ;) the .blg file contains only: 


    [0] 73b5ab1d.pm:320> INFO - This is Biber 1.9
    [0] 73b5ab1d.pm:323> INFO - Logfile is 'Minimalbeispiel.blg'

Comment: Have you tried running `biber` from the command line?

Comment: Is there any way to format code in the Comments? Now I've done it using "biber Minimalbeispiel.bcf" and it shows the following message: `code`
INFO - This is Biber 1.9
INFO - Logfile is 'Minimalbeispiel.blg'
read_file '/var/folders/_r/8f8_73vn7b3czxj6v01y50bh0000gn/T/par-6c6f72656e7a/cache-a3cdad92316c60c9c5179d80d6bb51a7a024393c//inc/lib/Biber/LaTeX/recode_data.xml' - sysopen: No such file or directory at /var/folders/_r/8f8_73vn7b3czxj6v01y50bh0000gn/T/par-6c6f72656e7a/cache-a3cdad92316c60c9c5179d80d6bb51a7a024393c/bda77484.pm line 112.

Comment: You can update your question with the code.  Anyway it looks like you have the "biber cache problem", see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/15925

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your biber cache got corrupted. For a quick fix:

1. Open Terminal
2. Enter the following: biber --cache
3. Remove the folder shown by the command

[Here](https://humtex.wordpress.com/2011/11/29/biber-first-aid-for-data-source-not-found/) is a more detailed description of the bug.