All of a sudden every latex project I have will not print a bibliography
So something truly strange has happened to me today, I was working on a LaTex project (my text editor is VScode) when all of a sudden I compiled my project and it spit out the the following error:

{Package biblatex: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)  main
(biblatex)  and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
LaTeX: Empty bibliography.

I was very confused because I did not even change the bibliography, or cite anything in the project I had only written standard stuff that spit out no errors.
After a couple ours of troubleshooting, I decided to open one my old projects to see what the difference was since I usually use roughly the same preamble for each large project like this, and the same set up for bibliographies. For reference, I use bibtex, and the following relevant code is what I put in each preamble:
\usepackage[
     backend=biber,
     style=numeric,
     sorting=none
     ]{biblatex}

\addresources{titleofproject.bib}

And then at the end of the project I write:
\printbibliography[
  heading=bibintoc,
  title={References}
  ]

I also use \documentclass{article} or documentclass{book} depending on the length of the project, but both types of projects are broken, when I haven't touched these documents in weeks to years. Anyways, I recompile my old projects without changing the code and nothing happens. Then I include a new \cite{1} line and all of sudden I start getting the same error. I remove this line and I still get the same error.
When I open the terminal and type biber main and press enter, I get the following statement on each document:

INFO - This is Biber 2.16
INFO - Logfile is 'main.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find 'main.bcf'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1

And I truly have no idea what this means. Any help on fixing this issue would be great, I do not know why all of sudden all of my latex project broke. I even created a new barebones latex project without any fluff (my preamble for projects like this can be a bit of mess) just to see if I could print a bibliography, and still nothing is working. I really have no idea what to make of this, and any help would be appreciated.
Edit:
Ok so I followed cabohah's advice, and using the minimal document they gave me I still got the same errors, however I also got

Package rerunfilecheck: File main.out' has changed.\ (rerunfilecheck)    Rerun to get outlines right\ (rerunfilecheck)    or use package bookmark'.

which is new and I have no idea what this means.
Here is the main.blg document:
[0] Config.pm:311> INFO - This is Biber 2.16
[0] Config.pm:314> INFO - Logfile is 'main.blg'
[64] biber-darwin:340> INFO - === Tue May 14, 2024, 09:57:50
[80] Biber.pm:415> INFO - Reading 'main.bcf'
[161] Biber.pm:949> INFO - Using all citekeys in bib section 0
[173] Biber.pm:4340> INFO - Processing section 0
[184] Biber.pm:4531> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'biblatex-examples.bib' for section 0
[330] bibtex.pm:1689> INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
[471] bibtex.pm:1494> INFO - Found BibTeX data source '/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/bibtex/bib/biblatex/biblatex/biblatex-examples.bib'
[513] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'laufenberg' (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/bibtex/bib/biblatex/biblatex/biblatex-examples.bib): Invalid format '2006-09-13' of date field 'date' - ignoring

Also, on my other documents I just get something like this (after commenting out almost all of my sections and putting one citation in):
[0] Config.pm:311> INFO - This is Biber 2.16
[0] Config.pm:314> INFO - Logfile is 'main.blg'
[62] biber-darwin:340> INFO - === Tue May 14, 2024, 09:57:10
[74] Biber.pm:415> INFO - Reading 'main.bcf'
[159] Biber.pm:952> INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
[171] Biber.pm:4340> INFO - Processing section 0
[179] Biber.pm:4531> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'cobordism.bib' for section 0
[180] bibtex.pm:1689> INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
[186] bibtex.pm:1494> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'cobordism.bib'

The main log output is too large to put in here, but here are some excerpts which contain the word warning:
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2021-02-27 v7.00k Hypertext links for LaTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)

as well as:
(./test.tex

LaTeX Warning: Citation '1' on page 1 undefined on input line 1.

)

LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 148.

[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./main.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                main
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'main.run.xml'.
\openout1 = `main.run.xml'.

 ) 

where test.tex is a tex file I have used the \input{test} command to include, after commenting out all other input commands. It contains the single command \cite{1}.

You first need a LaTeX run (e.g. pdflatex main) to generate the aux and bcf file, then the Biber run (e.g. biber main) should be successful, but you would still need two more LaTeX runs (yes, sometimes one more is enough, even if biblatex requests for one more). If this does not help, please show the log and the blg after doing the whole build (LaTeX + Biber + LaTeX + LaTeX) of a minimal example.

@cabohah So I run latex, then biber, then run latex two more times?

Yes. See the standard question and answer(s) for bibliography issues. BTW: For a minimal test document see, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283010/277964

@cabohah see my edit please. Thank you for your help

that means you are using the package rerunfilecheck specifically to give that warning, which is telling you to run pdflatex again to resolve all cross references and the pdf outline bookmarks

you have titleofproject.bib but your log shows you are using /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/bibtex/bib/biblatex/biblatex/biblatex-examples.bib  ?

@DavidCarlisle that is specifically the test file that cabohah gave me to run, I know nothing about that document. See my latest edit for the main.blg of something I did write

@DavidCarlisle this is also happening all of sudden across all of my projects which have all worked without issue in the past, so I feel like something has broken deeper than in the document itself.

@cabohah I have gone through your answer and nothing there seems to apply here, do you have any other suggestions?

the final log you show is completely normal. get a warning about undefined citations and a request to run biber, but then run biber and latex again,

@DavidCarlisle So then do you have any idea what could be wrong?

make a small complete document that references a small complete bib file and run through the full pdflatex, biber, pdflatex, pdflatex  process. If it works, there is something wrong in the documents you have not shown, if it does not work, show the full logs for each step

I don't think you have shown anything that suggests your cache is corrupted but removing the cache helps biber get unstuck sometimes see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234788/biblatex-and-textmate/234795#234795

@DavidCarlisle do you have an example I could emulate? I am "I frankensteined this stuff together out of stuff I saw online" type of LaTex user so I don't really understand how to build anything from scratch...

searching on this site for biblatex example suggests https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141957/the-most-basic-biblatex-example

Definitely clear the cache as discussed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/543837/35864. The .blg files shown in the question should not end where they end (there should be more content in these files). They also suggest you're on a Mac. These two facts together usually point to a corrupted cache.

If you get biblatex advice from @moewe and from me, do what moewe says:-)

If you want a simple example you can test, take the following document and compile it in a new, empty folder: https://gist.github.com/moewew/f78ff3d7cdc9f23ed6901bd7b929ea3f. The .bib file that is used and referenced there is installed on all systems with biblatex and will be found automatically (so you do not have to - and should not - create it). Compile that document with pdflatex <filename>, biber <filename>, pdflatex <filename>, pdflatex <filename> (where <filename> is the name of the file without .tex, e.g. bibermwe).

@moewe when I try to remove the cache it says it is a directory?

Yes, the Biber cache is spread out over a whole directory. You should delete the complete directory. (If you're working on the command line, you might have to rm -r instead of rm. Cf. also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140815/35864) Do note that the next Biber run after deleting the cache will take much longer than usual. That's because Biber has to unpack itself again. Do not stop the Biber run. Just wait for it to finish.

@moewe It's asking if I should overide x-xr-xr-x over and over again? Should I just keep saying yes?

Figured it out, that worked!

@Chris I guess so (I have never worked on a Mac, so I don't know the intricacies). Note that Alan's answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140815/35864 uses rm -rf, which probably ignores these questions and just gets on with deleting due to the force parameter. If the command line is giving you trouble you could also try using the GUI to remove the offending directory (though I'm not sure how happy Mac is to let you remove files like this)

rm -rf means r recurse in to the directory and f force (don't ask questions) it's what you want here but double double check that you apply it to the right thing.

That is exactly what I did and it worked, thank you very much
