# Bibliography and cite config

Tags: biblatex

I have a document that I want to set up to APA citation (cites and bibliography):

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text \cite{someone}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

How can I customize the cites and Bibliography at the end to meet the APA Standards? Thank you in advance

Comment: Why not simply use `\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=apa]{biblatex}`?

Comment: \documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[english, spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[hyperref=true, url=false,isbn=false, backref=true, backend=biber, citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=authoryear, maxcitenames=3, maxbibnames=100]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{backrefpage  = {ver p.}, backrefpages = {ver pp.}}

\begin{document}

\section{Introducción}\label{sec:intro}

E sustancialmente, aunque no de forma constante \cite{RecchinideLattesLattes1975}. 

\printbibliography
\end{document}

Comment: I get Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:́ not set up for use with LaTeX when I print the bibliography

Comment: Maybe try adding `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. Also, did you try with `backend=biber`? One advantage of biber is it understands `utf8`.

Comment: Yes, I try, same error message

Comment: Using biber I get this log when i run the \printbibliography
Undefined control sequence.
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Font shape `T1/lmr/bx/sc' undefined(Font) using `T1/lmr/bx/n' instead
Replacing `T1/lmr/bx/sc' by (spanish) faked small caps
destination with the same identifier (name{page.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored<to be read again> \relax l.189 [1
Overfull \hbox (6.03165pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (9.88014pt too wide) in paragraph
No file Notas.nls.
Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
Please rerun LaTeX.

Comment: `Biber` uses a cache, and it may happen this cache gets corrupted. You should delete it and retry.

Comment: That code will not give the log messages you posted. Please paste that code into a new `.tex` file, switch `backend=bibtex` to `backend=biber`, add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and see if that file compiles when you do pdflatex -> biber -> pdflatex -> pdflatex.

Comment: yes it does. i dont know what it's wrong with the long one then

Comment: How can you help me?

Comment: \documentclass[]{article}

%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Biblio.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
En este trabajo se construyen y analizan tablas de vida de cohorte para las cohortes de nacimiento de 1898 y de 1998 en la Argentina, con el objetivo de aportar una mirada complementaria y de largo plazo (dos siglos) a las investigaciones transversales de esperanza de vida al nacer.
\end{abstract}

*** why i get error from this?

Comment: Please try to find a minimal example that really shows an error and add it to the question, that way we can be sure we are all talking about the same thing. The snippet in your comment above compiles fine for me, but it doesn't contain any citations. What you are missing for `biblatex-apa` is the language mapping `\DeclareLanguageMapping{spanish}{spanish-apa}` (if you are writing in Spanish, that is).

Comment: % I have this code, but i get error everytime...how do i clean the biber cache?

\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[english, spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{spanish}{spanish-apa}
\addbibresource{Biblio.bib}

\begin{document}

asdasdasd \cite{Bhrolchain1992}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you are trying to compile, please also make sure that we have the necessary `.bib` file to run it. Ensure that the document encoding of all files involved is correct (UTF-8 in your case). Compile it with `pdflatex test`,`biber test`, `pdflatex test`, `pdflatex test` (assuming your file is called `test.tex`) ignoring any errors you might get. Then examine the `.log` file of the last LaTeX run and the `.blg` file and report any errors or warnings.

Comment: The Biber cache problem should be solved from version 2.2 onward, but you can find out about it in [Biblatex/biber fails with a strange error about missing recode_data.xml file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864). If you don't have the most recent versions of Biber and `biblatex`, an update might be a good idea, make sure that the versions match after the update, currently I have `biblatex 3.1` and Biber 2.2.

Comment: BTW You can ping users by mentioning their name with an `@` stuck to the front (like `@NicolásSacco`).

Comment: Are there any news here? Did you get your document going?

Comment: @Bernard Since you seem to have answered the question in the body text, would you mind writing up a short answer? (You could mention that `biblatex-apa` implements APA style to the letter, if one wants a simple author-year styles instead `authoryear` and friends might be better suited.)

Comment: @Moewe: Done. I added some  details for new users.

Answer (score 2):

The easier way to customise a bibliography is to load `biblatex` and compile the bibliography with `biber` which has possibilities that `bibtex` doesn't have, and understands `utf8`.

Biblatex uses a latex-like syntax, and  there exists a `biblatex-apa`package, which  implements APA style, and might be a starting point for customisation via the `xpatch` package. So I would write in the preamble

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

As mentioned by @moewe, for a simple author-year style, you can use one of the pre-defined styles with:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

Note the syntax used to produce the bibliography with `biblatex` is slightly different from  the syntax with `bibtex`: you have to write in the preamble:

```
\addbibresource{mybibfile.bib}
```

with the extension, and at the place where you want the bibliography, write

```
\printbibliography
```