# inputenc and bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, biber, input-encodings

I have this document, with problems building my bibliography

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[english, spanish]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=apa, bibstyle=authoryear-comp, sorting=ynt, url=false, isbn=false, doi=false, language=spanish, firstinits=true, hyperref=true, backref=true, maxcitenames=3, maxbibnames=10, mergedate=basic, firstinits=true, dashed=true]{biblatex}

%\inputencoding{latin1}
\addbibresource{Biblio.bib}
%\inputencoding{utf8}

\begin{document}
    \parencite{CoaleDemenyVaughan1983}
    \parencite{MacInnesPerezDiaz2008}
\parencite{Levy1993}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And the bib file is this:

```
@PhdThesis{PerezDiaz2001,
  Title                    = {Transformaciones sociodemogr{\'a}ficas en los recorridos hacia la madurez. Las generaciones espa{\~n}olas 1906-1945},
  Author                   = {P{\'e}rez D{\'\i}az, Julio},
  Type                     = {Thesis},
  Year                     = {2001},
  University               = {Universidad Nacional de Educaci{\'o}n a Distancia}
}

@Book{CoaleDemenyVaughan1983,
  Title                    = {Regional Model Life Tables and Stable Populations},
  Author                   = {Coale, Ansley J. and Demeny, Paul and Vaughan, Barbara},
  DOI                      = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-177080-8.50005-6},
  Edition                  = {Second},
  ISBN                     = {978-0-12-177080-8},
  Publisher                = {Academic Press},
  URL                      = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780121770808500056},
  Year                     = {1983},
  Address                  = {New York},
  Bdsk-url-1               = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780121770808500056},
  Bdsk-url-2               = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-177080-8.50005-6},
  Type                     = {Book}
}
```

So if I build without the `inputenc` package its fine, but with it, the first reference doesn work when I try to build the bibliography...Im writing in spanish and I export my references from endnote to jabref...Witch its the best process to avoid this problem????

Comment: Don't use {\'\i}, use the real char ï. Or call biber with --output-safechars. See also https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/65.

Comment: Input as  `\'e`  and `\~n` have sense  for the old times of BibTeX. Fortunately today, and specially using biblatex  you can  just   write "españolas" and "Pérez" as Ulrike suggest, but be sure that not only the .tex have the utf8 encoding. The  .bib file must have it too (In JabRef > File > Database properties, or in some  text editor as gedit or pluma >  File > Save as ...) .

Comment: Thats how i have my references in JabRef after exporting from EndNote...Any suggestion how to change it? I have in JabRef the utf8 encoding and the bib too...how do I call the --output-safechars <file>???

Comment: Please see [Input encoding error after upgrading from Biber 1.9 to Biber 2.1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251261/35864)

Comment: How does this question relate to [Bibliography and cite config](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/282715/35864)? Note that you are again missing the language mapping for `biblatex-apa` as discussed in the comments of the other question.

Comment: Any new here? I'm quite tempted to say this is an exact duplicate of [Input encoding error after upgrading from Biber 1.9 to Biber 2.1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251261/35864) where several solutions are discussed. In your case, the best seems to be to tell EndNote to export special characters sensibly either as UTF8 or the offending "í" as `\'i` and not `\'\i`.