# TexStudio with Jabref: compilation fails

Tags: bibliographies, texstudio, jabref

[image]I am using TexLive 2015 with TexStudio. I am editing my bibliography with Jabref.

I recently updated TexStudio and face bibliography compilation troubles since then.

When I compile, the log file indicates: "empty bibliography" and "undefined references". I guess this is due to an error in the path between Jabref and texstudio or a wrong setting in TexStudio. I changed the default bibliography tool in Texstudio to put Biber rather than Bibtex but the compilation doesn't work whatsoever.
My JabRef-generated literature file (thesegain2017.bib) is saved in the same folder than my tex-files.

My knwledge stops right here. Would someone have any idea on how to work this out? Many thanks !

Below my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-trad1, ibidtracker=context]{biblatex}
\renewcommand{\mkibid}[1]{\emph{#1}}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
\addbibresource{thesegain2017.bib}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}

\begin{document}

Blalalblla\autocite{Bourdieu1979}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Here is the `.bib` file:

```
 % This file was created with JabRef 2.10.
 % Encoding: UTF8

@Book{Bourdieu1979,
  Title                    = {La distinction, Critique sociale du jugement},
  Author                   = {Bourdieu, Pierre},
  Year                     = {1979},
  Location                 = {Paris},
  Pagetotal                = {670},
  Publisher                = {Les éditions de Minuit},

  Owner                    = {Mailys},
  Timestamp                = {2014.05.14}
 }
```

In the `.bbl` file I found that:

```
% $ biblatex auxiliary file $
% $ biblatex bbl format version 2.5 $
% Do not modify the above lines!
% This is an auxiliary file used by the 'biblatex' package.
% This file may safely be deleted. It will be recreated by
% biber as required.

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{ver@biblatex.sty}
{\@latex@error
{Missing 'biblatex' package}
{The bibliography requires the 'biblatex' package.}
  \aftergroup\endinput}
{}
\endgroup
```

But in the `.blg` file, I found that:

```
[0] 05015a72.pm:324> INFO - This is Biber 2.1
[0] 05015a72.pm:327> INFO - Logfile is 'my file.blg'
```

Comment: Using a working bibliography database, your MWE works without problems for me, so I can only guess that there is something wrong with your .bib file. Show us an example .bib file that contains the `Bourdieu1979` entry and gives the same error.

Comment: I am sorry, I not sure to understand your request. How am I supposed to show an example .bib file? I am very sorry to ask that.

Comment: I created a new .bib file with only one reference (Bourdieu1979) and the error persists.

Comment: The log file also indicates: Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) "my file"(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards. I don't know if this gives some clue :/

Comment: Then do as it says. Run biber then run again.

Comment: If by "run" it means "compile", I have already done that a bunch of time

Comment: Then there is something wrong with the .bib file. Please upload it.

Comment: To run biber again in TS, you can press `F8` (or through the menu "Tools" -> "Bibliography").

Comment: I added the information from my example.bib file but I not sure this is was you were waiting for. If not please tell me how to upload the .bib file. I didn't find any other way.

Comment: It works fine for me here. Did you try `F8` when it asks you to run biber again?

Comment: Are you actually running biber or is BibTeX run by your editor? Have a look at the `blg` file.

Comment: Yes I tried F8 many times without any better result.

Comment: @Johannes_B : What (and how) should I look for at the `blg` file? I don't really know if it's running in biber or BibTex. I just know that I changed the default bibliography tool in Texstudio to put Biber rather than Bibtex.

Comment: In the folder with your main and bib files are other files, maybe Windows is hiding the extension. Open them all one by one in a simple text editor. You will find a line like *This is BibTeX* or *this is biber* at the beginning. The content is important.

Comment: which version of TexStudio? `2.12.8`?

Comment: @Johannes_B, I added the information you ask in the body of my question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JonasStein, I think it is the latest. I made an update few days ago. It is : TeXstudio `2.12.6`

Comment: If the Biber run succeeded the `.blg` should contain much more than just those two lines. Is there anything more? Can you compile from the command line? You are using a very old version of Biber (current is 2.10) and `biblatex` (current is 3.10). Try deleting the cache: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864

Comment: @moewe, Thanks a lot. There is nothing more in the `.blg`. I am actually trying to delete the cache but I can't find it anywhere. I tried the different paths mentioned. Would it be possible to solve the problem by uploading the latest version of Biber and biblatex?

Comment: If you can run Biber from the command line (google command line and your OS to find how to get there), use `biber --cache` to get the cache location. It really should be somewhere. It might be possible to solve the problem by updating, but updating is a risk if you close to a project deadline. And updating would in your case mean installing anew TeX live 2017. What OS are you using?

Comment: @moewe, I opened the command line. I just copied and pasted : `biber --cache` (I not sure that it is the right way to do it) but the answer is (my trslation from French): "biber is not reconnized as an internal or external command, or an executable program, or a file of command"

Comment: @moewe, I am using windows 10. and I am indeed fews days from a major project deadline.

Comment: That is the right way. The TeX executables are just not in path and are not found. Do you know where you have installed TeX into? Can you show a screenshot of your TeXstudio settings (Preferences/Build)?

Comment: @moewe, I add the screenshot of my `Texstudio` settings in my core question. The path for my `TexLive` is `C:\texlive` and for `TexStudio` is this one: `C:\Program Files (x86)\TeXstudio\texstudio.exe`. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Can you find `biber.exe` anywhere in `C:\texlive` or its subfolders?

Comment: I found it here: `C:\texlive\2015\bin\win32\biber.exe`

Comment: OK. Open the command line again. Type in `cd C:\texlive\2015\bin\win32\ ` and hit enter. The prompt should show that you are now in that path. Then type `biber --cache` if that does not work try `.\biber.exe --cache`. Do you get an output?

Comment: No, I get the same empty output as previously. I tried both way unsuccesfully. Weirdly enough, I get the same empty output when entering in cd:`C:\texlive\2015\bin\win32\`

Comment: Also with `.\biber.exe --cache`? If you start typing `biber` and hit the Tab key, does it autocomplete to Biber? Even though you are in `cd C:\texlive\2015\bin\win32\ `? Does it say `C:\texlive\2015\bin\win32\>` before the cursor?

Comment: Actually, `C:\texlive\2015\bin\win32\` is not reconized either. Did I miss something is the process?

Comment: Open the command line. Type `cd C:\texlive\2015\bin\win32` and press enter. Then try (in that order) `biber --cache`, `biber.exe --cache`, `.\biber.exe --cache`.

Comment: It's what I have been doing without any other result than: "not reconnized as an internal or external command, or an executable program, or a file of command" Even: `C:\texlive\2015\bin\win32` "is not reconnized as an internal or external command, or an executable program, or a file of command".

Comment: OK. Close the command line and open it again. What does the bit before `>` say?

Comment: C:\Users\MyName>

Comment: Good. Type cd C:\. Do you now see `C:\>`? Then type in `cd texlive\2015\bin\win32`. Do you see `C:\texlive\2015\bin\win32>`?

Comment: I am sorry but I still get the same message

Comment: At what step do you get it? Can you do cd C:\? Can you do `cd C:\texlive` can you do `cd C:\texlive\2015`? Can you do `cd C:\texlive\2015\bin`? Can you do `cd C:\texlive\2015\bin\win32`?

Comment: It went wrong first step: C:/

Comment: Did you type `cd C:`? *With* `cd`?

Comment: Ooh sorry, I didn't get it this way. I did with `cd` and I do see `C:\texlive\2015\bin\win32>` !

Comment: then plus `biber --cache` I get: `C:\Users\mailys\AppData\Local\Temp\par-6d61696c7973\cache-48b1414b522013718507ac7cc0b21aa1f37b24ea\recode_data.xml` ! And this is the very file I cannot found manually.

Comment: Ah! Finally. Find `C:\Users\mailys\AppData\Local\Temp\par-6d61696c7973` and delete the entire folder.

Comment: I cannot find it neither manually nor with a research in windows

Comment: You may have to tell Windows to show hidden files: https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/help/14201/windows-show-hidden-files

Comment: OK. How far do you get? Can you get to `C:\Users\mailys\AppData\Local\Temp`?

Comment: I finally found and (hopefully) delete the file. Let's what is happening now with TexStudio... :)

Comment: I don't really have high hopes. We may have to run Biber manually.

Comment: Well, I don't know for how long but it seems to be incredibly working ! Thank you soooo much @moewe !!!

Comment: Brilliant! Glad I could help. I voted to close as duplicate of the 'delete your cache question'.

Comment: Yes. sure. I read this Q&A but I couln't manage my way alone. Thanks again !

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73299/discussion-on-question-by-mailysmanu-texstudio-with-jabref-compilation-fails).