# Citation XXX on page 1 undefined and empty bibliography

Tags: biblatex, citing, texmaker, biber

I was making a thesis documentation using Texmaker and I achieve it by using a main tex file where all of its associated tex files can be inputted to the main tex file when required.

I was stuck on this portion of the PDF output, where the citation looks awful and I couldn't see the bibliography.

The PDF output looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Instead of seeing the green clickable box of the citation, all I see is the word "Beal'2018", which is the citation name for "Beal_2018".

I used 4 tex files to make the PDF with the citations, but I couldn't make it work. I don't know where I messed up.

These are the codes I used to make the PDF file. The code below is the main tex file I used to make the PDF...

```
\documentclass[reqno,12pt,onecolumn]{report}
\input{ECEThesispreamble2014Mar19}
% right side numbers for equations
% text size is 12 pt
% document has one column
% CONFIGURE (Options) Bibtex file to ...biber.exe"%
% or ...biber.exe"%.bcf

%SINCE THIS USES BIBER FOLLOW THE STEPS BELOW
%IF YOU ADD NEW CITATIONS:
% F2: Latex
% F11: Bibtex (Biber)
% F11: Bibtex (Biber)
% F2: Latex
% F2: Latex
% F1: Quickbuild
%==========================================================
%-----> REFERENCE DATABASE FROM THE GROUP MEMBERS
%-----> REQUIRED IN ECE 419
%-----> TO BE UPDATED DURING ECE 507, 508
\addbibresource{WhizzKids.bib} %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%==========================================================
\begin{document}
%\pagenumbering{roman} %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%-----> FILE CONTAINING THE COVER PAGE
%-----> REQUIRED IN ECE 419, 507, 508
%\input{WhizzKidsCover} %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%XXXXXXXX\newpage
%-----> FILE CONTAINING THE APPROVAL SHEET
%-----> REQUIRED IN ECE 508
%XXXXXXXX\input{GroupName_Thesis_ApprovalSheet_2013Mar07} 
%XXXXXXXX\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}}
%==========================================================
%\newpage %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract} %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\chapter*{Abstract} %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%-----> FILE CONTAINING THE ABSTRACT
%-----> REQUIRED IN ECE 508
%\input{AbstractX} %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%==========================================================
% \newpage %(Comment/Uncomment this)
% \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgment} %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\chapter*{Acknowledgment} %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%-----> FILE(S) CONTAINING THE ACKNOWLEDGEMNT 
%-----> REQUIRED IN ECE 508
%\input{AcknowledgmentX} %(Comment/Uncomment this) 
%==========================================================
%COMMANDS FOR TABLE OF CONTENTS
%\newpage %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\tableofcontents %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%==========================================================
%COMMANDS FOR LIST OF TABLES
%\newpage %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect List of Tables} %(Comment/Uncomment this)
{
%\addtocontents{lot}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par} %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\renewcommand{\cftdot}{ } %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\makeatletter %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\listoftables %(Comment/Uncomment this)
}
%==========================================================
%COMMANDS FOR LIST OF FIGURES
%\newpage %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect List of Figures}       %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%{
%\addtocontents{lof}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par} %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\renewcommand{\cftdot}{ } %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\makeatletter %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\listoffigures %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%}
%==========================================================
%START OF ARABIC PAGINATION
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%==========================================================
%\chapter{INTRODUCTION} %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\label{chap:intro} %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%-----> FILE(S) FOR THE INTRODUCTION
%-----> REQUIRED IN ECE 419
%-----> MUST BE UPDATED IN ECE 507, 508
%\input{Chapter1} %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%==========================================================
\chapter{THEORETICAL BACKGROUND}
\label{chap:theoretical}
%-----> FILE(S) FOR THE THEORETICAL BACKGROUND
%-----> REQUIRED IN ECE 419
%-----> MUST BE UPDATED IN ECE 507, 508
\input{Chapter2} %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%==========================================================
%\chapter{RESEARCH METHODOLOGY}
%\label{chap:method} %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%-----> FILE(S) FOR THE METHODOLOGY
%-----> REQUIRED IN ECE 419
%-----> MUST BE UPDATED IN ECE 507, 508
%\input{Chapter3} %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%==========================================================
%\chapter{RESULTS AND DISCUSSIONS}
%\label{chap:results} %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%-----> FILE(S) FOR THE RESULTS AND DISCUSSIONS
%-----> REQUIRED IN ECE 507
%-----> MUST BE UPDATED IN ECE508
%\input{Chapter4}  %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%==========================================================
%\chapter{CONCLUSIONS AND RECOMMENDATIONS}
%XXXXXXXX\label{chap:conclusion}
%-----> FILE(S) FOR THE CONCLUSIONS AND RECOMMENDATIONS
%-----> REQUIRED IN ECE 508
%\input{Chapter5}  %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%==========================================================
\newpage %(Comment/Uncomment this)
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{BIBLIOGRAPHY} %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%keywords should be included as one of the fields in the bib file
%the bib files are loaded using \addbibresource in the preamble
\chapter*{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
\printbibliography[keyword=Books, heading=subbibliography,title={Books}]
\printbibliography[keyword=Published, heading=subbibliography,title={Published}]
\printbibliography[keyword=Unpublished, heading=subbibliography,title={Unpublished}]
\printbibliography[keyword=Electronic Sources, heading=subbibliography,title={Electronic Sources}]
%==========================================================
%\newpage %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\appendix %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\renewcommand{\chaptername}{\appendixname} %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect                \chaptername{\appendixname}} %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\chapter{PRIOR ART SEARCH AND ANALYSIS REPORT}
%-----> REQUIRED IN ECE 419
%-----> MUST BE UPDATED IN ECE 507, 508
%\input{App_PASAR_Balleno} %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\newpage %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\input{App_PASAR_CaNo} %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\newpage %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\input{App_PASAR_Doron} %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\newpage %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\chapter{TIMETABLE OF ACTIVITIES}
%-----> REQUIRED IN ECE 419
%-----> MUST BE UPDATED IN ECE 507, 508
%\input{WhizzKidsTimetable} %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\newpage %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\chapter{RESEARCH BUDGET}
%-----> REQUIRED IN ECE 419
%-----> MUST BE UPDATED IN ECE 507, 508
% \input{App_Budget} %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\newpage %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%XXXXXXXX\chapter{ADDITIONAL FLOWCHARTS}
%-----> IF APPLICABLE
%-----> REQUIRED IN ECE 507
%-----> MUST BE UPDATED IN 508
%XXXXXXXX\input{App_Flowcharts}
%XXXXXXXX\newpage
%XXXXXXXX\chapter{PSEUDO-CODES}
%-----> IF APPLICABLE
%-----> REQUIRED IN ECE 507
%-----> MUST BE UPDATED IN 508
%XXXXXXXX\input{App_Codes}
%XXXXXXXX\newpage
%\chapter{ELECTRICAL CIRCUITS}
%-----> IF APPLICABLE
%-----> REQUIRED IN ECE 507
%-----> MUST BE UPDATED IN 508
%\input{Circuit}
%\newpage
%\chapter{CURRICULUM VITAE}
%-----> REQUIRED IN ECE 508
%\input{Balleno} %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\newpage %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\input{CaNo} %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\newpage %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\input{Doron} %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%\newpage %(Comment/Uncomment this)
%XXXXXXXX\input{App_CV_member2}
%==========================================================
\end{document}
```

Just ignore those commented parts because they are not needed.

This is the preamble code associated with the main tex file to make a PDF output.

```
%DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv} % Arial
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv} % Arial
% set font to Arial
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1.5in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,epstopdf}
\usepackage{rotating,marvosym,multirow,rotating,longtable}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
% set the margins
\usepackage{amsmath,amsxtra,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
% various AMS packages
\usepackage{csquotes}
%you can put double quotation marks now
\usepackage{graphicx,rotating,epsfig,epstopdf}
% insert and rotate images
%\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocloft}
% modify toc, lot, lof
\usepackage{afterpage,subcaption}
% subfigures in a figure: subfigure can replace subcaption
\usepackage{setspace}
% allows you to specify the line spacing
\doublespacing 
\usepackage{hyphenat}
%[none] no hyphenation
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
% text superscript or subscript
\usepackage{multirow,titlesec}
% tables with multiple rows and edit chapter format
\usepackage{indentfirst,mdwlist,array}
% always indent the first paragraph
% compact version of list environments
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmicx,algpseudocode}
% insert pseudo-codes in the document
\usepackage{morefloats,easylist,paralist,enumitem,rotfloat}
% increase the maximum number of figures
% nested list with a depth > 4
% inline list
\usepackage{url,hyperref,gloss}
% url: for bibliography with type misc, howpublished=\url{}
% hyperref: autoref of numbered items and bibliography field: url = 
% gloss: create a glossary
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
%use colors for texts and tables
\usepackage{pgfgantt,tikz,pgf}
% pgfgantt: produce Ghantt charts
% tikz: graphics using commands (w/pgf)
% pgf: 
\usepackage{longtable}
%==========================================================
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
% change the title of toc
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
% centered and bold header for toc
\usepackage{titletoc}
% title of toc
\titlecontents*{chapter}% <section-type>
[0pt]% <left>
{}% <above-code>
{\bfseries\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel \quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
{\bfseries\ \thecontentslabel }% <numberless-entry-format>
{\bfseries \hfill \contentspage \\}% <filler-page-format>
% add Chapter to each chapter in toc and no dots
\titlecontents*{section}
[0pt]
{}
{\hspace{65pt} \thecontentslabel \quad}
%{\quad \quad \quad \quad \thecontentslabel \quad}
{}
{\hfill \contentspage \\}
% remove dots
\titlecontents*{subsection}
[0pt]
{}
{\hspace{95pt} \thecontentslabel \quad}
%{\quad \quad \quad \quad \thecontentslabel \quad}
{}
{\hfill \contentspage \\}
% remove dots

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{12pt}
%\titlespacing*{command}{left}{before-sep}{after-sep}[right-sep]

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont \normalfont \bfseries         \centering }{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{8pt}{\normalfont \bfserie \centering}
% control the output of \chapter{}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
% control the output of \section{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
% control the output of \subsection{}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfill\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hfill}
% change the title of lot
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}
% change the title of lof
%==========================================================
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
% appendices in the thesis
%==========================================================
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=ieee,sorting=rmc,defernumbers=true]            {biblatex}
\DeclareSortingScheme{rmc}{
\sort{
\field{keywords} 
}
}
%END OF PREAMBLE
```

There is also no problem in the preamble because I didn't modify the preamble above.

This is the bib file I used to make a citation...

```
@misc{Beal_2018,
    keywords= "Electronic Sources",
    author = "Beal, Vangie", 
    title = "application (application software)", 
    howpublished = "\url{https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/A/application.html}",     
    year = "2018",       
}
```

I believe that there is something in the bib file above that makes the bibliography not working.

This is the associated tex file I used to make the PDF....

```
\section{What is an application?}

An application (also called application software), is any program that is designed for the end user. Application software includes database programs, word processors, Web browsers and spreadsheets. In the Fig.~ \ref{fig:application}...\\

\begin{figure}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.60]{Chapter2Picture1.jpg}
  \caption {Softwares \cite{Beal_2018}.} 
  \label{fig:application}
\end{figure}


Applications sit on top of systems software because they are cannot run without the operating system and system utilities. Systems software consists of low-level programs that interact with the computer at basic level. This includes operating systems, compilers, and utilities for managing computer resources \cite{Beal_2018}.\\
```

The associated tex file above might be the culprit on why the citations doesn't work....

This is the error message when I "run" the main tex file....

[image]

How could I resolve the problem of citations and bibliography?

Comment: Did you run Biber (as suggested in the comments in your last screen shot)? Please see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help on setting your editor up for Biber. If you did run LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) and still get no output, please show us the `.blg` file. On Windows machines `.blg` files will be classified as 'Performance monitor files' but they are just plain text files you can open with your favourite editor. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864

Comment: @moewe Yes...I configured the Texmaker to run on "Biber"....The sequence to run it was "Latex - Biber - Biber - Latex -Latex"....

Comment: Good, then show us the `.blg` file (see comment above about it being a text file even though Windows claims it is not).

Comment: Note that your system is pretty old. Your pdfLaTeX format is three and a half years old. You may want to consider a proper update (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864) before you continue. If you are already working and have a close deadline updates can be risky, but if your system is really old it could be unavoidable.

Comment: @moewe Using Notepad, I was able to see the contents of the .blg file. It looks like this, a text file:  [1] Config.pm:361> INFO - This is Biber 1.5
[2] Config.pm:364> INFO - Logfile is 'WhizzKidsMain.blg'

Comment: Is that all or is there more? Please add the full text of the `.blg` file to your question. The only thing I can say now is that Biber 1.5 is ancient, it is roughly five and a half years old.

Comment: @moewe Yes...That's all I could see. There is other way to open the .blg file using Resource and Performance Monitor but it looks empty. I didn't realize that the softwares I used were dinosaurs...

Comment: Do not use the performance monitor. Open it in a text editor. (Notepad, Notepad++, TeXstudio, TeXmaker, ... you name it all of them should be able to open the file). If the file just stops after `INFO - Logfile is 'WhizzKidsMain.blg'` I can't really help you. That means the run aborted or hangs so early that not even a warning or useful error is produced.

Comment: @moewe I don't understand....The blg file has changed its contents. Now it looks like this:   This is BibTeX, Version 0.99dThe top-level auxiliary file: WhizzKidsMain.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file WhizzKidsMain.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file WhizzKidsMain.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file WhizzKidsMain.aux
(There were 3 error messages)

Comment: That means you ran BibTeX instead of Biber. But your document needs Biber. FWIW You only need to compile LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX. The second Biber run is superfluous.

Comment: @moewe When I configure the Texmaker to use the Bibtex, the blg file's text output is:  This is BibTeX, Version 0.99dThe top-level auxiliary file: WhizzKidsMain.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file WhizzKidsMain.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file WhizzKidsMain.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file WhizzKidsMain.aux (There were 3 error messages)..........
   When I configure the Texmaker to use the Biber, the blg file's text output is: [1] Config.pm:361> INFO - This is Biber 1.5
[2] Config.pm:364> INFO - Logfile is 'WhizzKidsMain.blg'

Comment: Yeah, like is said, the correct configuration is for Biber. But the Biber run aborts prematurely (apparently). The only advice I have at the moment is to do an update to move from your ancient system to a more current one.

Comment: @moewe or perhaps I forgot some particular file to be moved when I tried to move the needed files from Drive C: to Drive D: ......but thanks for helping me out, man!

Comment: Mhh, it is really not clear what is wrong. Biber aborts so early that there is no way to tell what is going on there.

Comment: @moewe perhaps this error may make it a hint. This error appears on Texmaker: Process started

data source C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\par-61646d696e\cache-890efc00b3ca6b775c7d44a325c1349fb2a3a3bd\recode_data.xml not found in .

INFO - This is Biber 1.5 INFO - Logfile is 'WhizzKidsMain.blg'

Process exited with error(s)      .....All of my files related to Texmaker & Latex were in drive D:, but somehow, somewhere along the internal workings of Latex that it still tries to access drive C:, so it might mean I might have forgotten one tiny file that should be relocated in drive D:...

Comment: Ohhh, that is a helpful message. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864.

Comment: Do let us know if https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864 solved your problem, please.

Comment: Voted to close as duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864. Please ask a new question or edit this one if that did not help.

Comment: @moewe Yes...it solved my problem after reading that post you have shown....All I had to do was to erase the temp files of my laptop running Windows 8...The citations and bibliographies now work and I can click the little green box of the citation...:-)

Comment: If you are stuck with that older version of yours it may happen that you have to delete your cache more than once (or indeed more regularly). This is a bug in a utility used by Biber that has since been resolved. Biber versions >= 2.2 should not have this problem any more. The current version is 2.11.