# Biblatex not compiling

Tags: biblatex

Biblatex is not working for me suddenly. I suddenly get the following log file :

```
Unsuccessful stat on filename containing newline at /var/folders/48/mcfj3ms5211f4zc_b6l9680r0000gn/T/par-6a61736f6e6b6861646b61/cache-6bef3f811cde577dd70e44f9f5046ebc66712c46/inc/lib/XML/LibXML/Simple.pm line 223.
data source <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bcf:controlfile version="2.7" xmlns:bcf="https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex">
  <!-- BIBER OPTIONS -->
  <bcf:options component="biber" type="global">
    <bcf:option type="singlevalued">
      <bcf:key>output_encoding</bcf:key>
      <bcf:value>utf8</bcf:value>
    </bcf:option>
    <bcf:option type="singlevalued">
      <bcf:key>input_encoding</bcf:key>
      <bcf:value>utf8</bcf:value>
    </bcf:option>
    <bcf:option type="singlevalued">
 .....
      <bcf:field>addendum</bcf:field>
      <bcf:field>afterword</bcf:field>
      <bcf:field>annotator</bcf:field>
      <bcf:field>com not found in .
INFO - This is Biber 2.1
INFO - Logfile is 'main.blg'
INFO - Reading 'main.bcf'
```

and in the compiling of my text there is an error that can only fixed by recompiling the biblatex. How can i fix it?

Comment: Since you are using Biber 2.1 it could be the error described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864. Versions from 2.2 onwards should not suffer from this cache problem. The current version of Biber is 2.12. Is there a chance you can update your TeX distribution (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864).

Comment: You may also want to try deleting all auxiliary files (`.aux`, `.bbl` and in particular `.bcf`) and recompiling from scratch with LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX.

Comment: Any news here? Did deleting the temporary files and/or the cache work?

Comment: hi @moewe, thanks for your reply. in the end that is what i ended up doing, deleting all the extra files and recompiling. and it worked! Thanks for the suggestion!