# I keep getting the "infamous" cache error in Biber even with version 2.13

Tags: biber

I have been looking at the following TeX StackExchange questions:

- [Biblatex/biber fails with a strange error about missing recode_data.xml file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140814/biblatex-biber-fails-with-a-strange-error-about-missing-recode-data-xml-file)
- [Troubleshooting for biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286706/troubleshooting-for-biber)

Alas, even after deleting the cache AND checking that my `biber --version` is 2.13 (so, greather than 2.2), I keep getting the infamous:

> ```
> ERROR - Error loading data source package 'Biber::Input::file::biblatex':
> Can't locate Biber/Input/file/biblatex.pm in @INC
> (you may need to install the Biber::Input::file::biblatex module)
> (@INC contains:
> C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\par-696e6e6f766163696f6e\cache-04a19264eaffcea447b2351b2a1f132a70bdc8b1\inc\lib
> C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\par-696e6e6f766163696f6e\cache-04a19264eaffcea447b2351b2a1f132a70bdc8b1\inc
> CODE(0x3711510) CODE(0x3711708)) at (eval 366) line 1.
> ```

Comment: There is indeed no `Biber/Input/file/biblatex.pm` at all. There is only `bibtex.pm` and `biblatexml.pm`. So Biber shouldn't be trying to look for that file at all. Can you run `biber --version` without error? Can you run a very simple MWE like https://gist.github.com/moewew/6e738db2c03f1e1a2653e33d3101b524 without error? If those run without error, can you please show us a complete `.tex` document that reproduces the issue?

Comment: 1. Yep, `biber --version` gives 2.13 without error; 2. The MWE works, alright. 3. I will work on providing a minimal "breaking" example.

Comment: While working on the MBE I discovered the error, apparently the option `[datatype=biblatex]` for `addbibresource` was at fault (I don't really know where I copied that from).
Now the problem is that because I set the output folder as `./pdf/`, xelatex is unable to find the bbl file and thus I still have undefined references.

Comment: We'd need to know more about your editor setup and workflow to answer the question about the `./pdf/` folder, so I suggest you ask a new question about that. I should mention that output/build folders like `./pdf/` usually cause much more trouble than they are worth, so you may want to consider just dropping it.

Comment: Consider accepting the provided solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, this is not the infamous cache bug.

This error can be reproduced in the following document

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource[datatype=biblatex]{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And it occurs if the `datatype` key of `\addbibresource` gets passed an unknown value. Currently the only accepted values are `bibtex` (for `.bib` files) and `biblatexml` (for `.bltxml` files). All other values will cause Biber to try and load non-existing files.

I opened https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/289 to discuss making the error message a bit more useful.

Comment: +1: Perfect answer! Why are there no upvotes?

Comment: Just to confirm, this is fixed in recent versions of biber which will give an error and report valid datatypes.