# Biber 2.14 broken ? - Biber warning: [557] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry ...' (....bib): Invalid format '2018' of date field 'date' - ignoring

Tags: biber

**EDIT Downgrading biber and updating it again (with tex Live) solved it**:

```
➜  latex tlmgr restore biber
Available backups for biber: 50203 (2020-02-05 09:07)
➜  latex tlmgr restore biber 50203
Do you really want to restore biber to revision 50203 (y/N): y
Restoring biber, 50203 from /usr/local/texlive/2019/tlpkg/backups/biber.r50203.tar.xz
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
running mtxrun --generate ...
done running mtxrun --generate.
tlmgr: package log updated: /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
➜  biber -v
biber version: 2.14

Run Tex Live and update biber, should work now
```

I tried to compile my work that used to work a few days ago, and Biber 2.14 cannot parse any dates from my bib file any more. I have pages and pages of the following errors (and no reference is added to the output).

This used to compile without any errors before (the '...' is just to remove the noise).

Errors with the latest biber (before restoring using the above commands):

```
Biber warning: [558] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '2019-05-17' of date field 'urldate' - ignoring
Biber warning: [563] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '2013' of date field 'date' - ignoring
Biber warning: [563] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '2018-12-15' of date field 'urldate' - ignoring
Biber warning: [573] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '2008' of date field 'date' - ignoring
Biber warning: [583] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '2014' of date field 'date' - ignoring 
Biber warning: [584] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '2019-05-19' of date field 'urldate' - ignoring 
Biber warning: [588] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '2017' of date field 'date' - ignoring
Biber warning: [589] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '2018-12-27' of date field 'urldate' - ignoring
Biber warning: [591] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '1997' of date field 'date' - ignoring
Biber warning: [592] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '2019-05-18' of date field 'urldate' - ignoring
Biber warning: [602] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '2019-06-01' of date field 'date' - ignoring
Biber warning: [603] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '2020-02-16' of date field 'urldate' - ignoring
Biber warning: [608] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '2005' of date field 'date' - ignoring
Biber warning: [611] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '2016' of date field 'date' - ignoring 
Biber warning: [611] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '2020-02-26' of date field 'urldate' - ignoring 
Biber warning: [618] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '2018' of date field 'date' - ignoring 
Biber warning: [618] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '2018-12-15' of date field 'urldate' - ignoring 
Biber warning: [623] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '2016' of date field 'date' - ignoring
Biber warning: [624] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '2019-05-10' of date field 'urldate' - ignoring
Biber warning: [629] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '2004' of date field 'date' - ignoring
Biber warning: [629] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '2018-12-15' of date field 'urldate' - ignoring
Biber warning: [634] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '1999' of date field 'date' - ignoring 
Biber warning: [635] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '2019-07-09' of date field 'urldate' - ignoring 
Biber warning: [637] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '2006' of date field 'date' - ignoring
Biber warning: [637] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '2019-07-07' of date field 'urldate' - ignoring
Biber warning: [648] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '2017' of date field 'date' - ignoring
Biber warning: [648] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '2018-12-27' of date field 'urldate' - ignoring
Biber warning: [656] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '2019' of date field 'date' - ignoring
Biber warning: [657] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '2019-07-02' of date field 'urldate' - ignoring
Biber warning: [662] Utils.pm:304> WARN - Entry '...' (x.bib): Invalid format '2015' of date field 'date' - ignoring
```

**EDIT, a sample that would be rejected:**

x.bib

```
@article{parisAntisocialBorderlinePersonality1997,
  title = {Antisocial and Borderline Personality Disorders: {{Two}} Separate Diagnoses or Two Aspects of the Same Psychopathology?},
  shorttitle = {Antisocial and Borderline Personality Disorders},
  author = {Paris, Joel},
  date = {1997},
  journaltitle = {Comprehensive Psychiatry},
  shortjournal = {Comprehensive Psychiatry},
  volume = {38},
  pages = {237--242},
  issn = {0010440X},
  doi = {10.1016/S0010-440X(97)90032-8},
  url = {https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0010440X97900328},
  urldate = {2019-05-18},
  langid = {english},
  number = {4}
}
```

sample.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,floatsintext,12pt]{apa6}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\addbibresource{x.bib}
\authornote{x}
\title{x}
\shorttitle{x}
\author{x}
\affiliation{x}
\abstract{
x
}
\keywords{x}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\parencite{parisAntisocialBorderlinePersonality1997}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Command

```
latexmk -pdf -xelatex
```

Comment: Can you please share an entry of `x.bib` with us and a short example document that cites such an entry? I can not reproduce the warnings you are getting.

Comment: Is a year a valid date? I have no issues with it using TL19 frozen, using pdflatex as I don't have that font. BTW: `latexmk -pdf -xelatex` does not make sense, you are asking for both `pdflatex` and `xelatex` drop the `-pdf` as PDF output is the default for `xelatex` anyway

Comment: Mhhh, the entry works absolutely fine for me in a small example document using a standard style as well as in your larger document using `apa` style. Can you please test the MWEs from https://gist.github.com/moewew/f54f200adb65399edb6cdad8a7ca2077 (the MWEs are compilable without any changes, so please do not modify them before you run them)? Please upload the full `.blg` file of the failing runs to your question. (The `.blg` file isn't long and should easily fit into the question. `.blg` files can be opened with any text editor.)

Comment: @moewe thanks heaps for setting it up, I re-updated biber (with nothing but fear) and all my documents are still compiling just fine. I'm not sure what caused it, the only suspicion I have is that other libraries put something in place that prevented biber from working? I'm really not sure. I'll leave the answer here (rollback-reupdate), just in case someone faces this again. Thanks again!

Comment: Mhh, since Biber comes bundled with all its dependencies and libraries I'd expect it is unlikely that some other piece of software would cause this issue. (It would have been interesting to see the full `.blg` file, ideally it would have contained a few more lines that could give a hint as to what was going wrong.) Since Biber comes bundled with all its dependencies, it needs to be unpacked on first run. If this unpacking step goes wrong for some reason, weird errors can occur. ...

Comment: ... This used to be a very common issue (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864), but even though that particular problem is fixed now, I am convinced that in principle structurally similar issues could arise.

Comment: Thanks, @moewe, if something similar occurs later again then I'll back up the whole folder (including .blg) to make sure we can find again what caused it.

Answer (score 1):

As above, rolling it back from the command line (`latex tlmgr restore biber`) then updating it again to the latest version solved the problem. I'm not sure what caused it (maybe the order of the install with other packages...?)

Further edit, the Biber cache got corrupted, so the steps that can solve this are:

Clean the build

`latexmk -c`

And clear the biber cache

`` rm -rf `biber --cache` ``