# biber generates empty bbl-file

Tags: biblatex, biber, bbl

Compiling the following tex-file with `pdflatex` in a terminal window and running biber I get an empty bbl-file. I looked at the answer to similar problems but without success. This happens since the last update via `tlmgr` I did some days ago (repeating it some minutes ago).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}  
%
@book{schaefer:bl,
    Author = {Helmut H. Schaefer},
    Keywords = {Schaefer},
    Publisher = {Springer},
    Title = {Banach Lattices and Positive Operators},
    Year = {1974}}
%
@article{schaefer:1967,
    Author = {Helmut H. Schaefer},
    Journal = {Illinois J. Math.},   
    Pages = {703--715},
    Title = {Invariant ideals of positive operators in $C(X)$ (I)},
    Volume = {11},
    Year = {1967}}
%
\end{filecontents}  
\usepackage[%
    ,backend=biber
    ,style=numeric 
    ,giveninits = true]{biblatex}  
%
\bibliography{mybib}   
\listfiles   
\begin{document}  
\cite{schaefer:1967,schaefer:bl}
%  
\printbibliography      
\end{document}
```

My versions of the programs:

```
pdflatex --version: 
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020)
kpathsea version 6.3.2

biber --version: 
biber version: 2.14

biblatex:
2019/12/01 v3.14

biber --debug gives the following:
INFO - This is Biber 2.14
INFO - Logfile is 'mwe-literatur.blg'
INFO - DEBUG mode: all messages are logged to 'mwe-literatur.blg'
INFO - Reading 'mwe-literatur.bcf'
INFO - Found 2 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Globbing data source 'mybib.bib'
INFO - Globbed data source 'mybib.bib' to mybib.bib
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'mybib.bib' for section 0
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "aug"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "may"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "jul"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "dec"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "jun"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "apr"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "jan"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "nov"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "oct"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "feb"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "sep"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "mar"
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'mybib.bib'
Unicode::UCD: failed to find unicore/version in /var/folders/x2/95kn6jvs4dxbrhq1__t4fgc40000gn/T/par-7567726f68/cache-2f8a664c3c933a44d096bcc8d018a5e92bced897/inc/lib /var/folders/x2/95kn6jvs4dxbrhq1__t4fgc40000gn/T/par-7567726f68/cache-2f8a664c3c933a44d096bcc8d018a5e92bced897/inc CODE(0x7fc559816840) CODE(0x7fc559816e28) at /var/folders/x2/95kn6jvs4dxbrhq1__t4fgc40000gn/T/par-7567726f68/cache-2f8a664c3c933a44d096bcc8d018a5e92bced897/inc/lib/Biber/Input/file/bibtex.pm line 1011.
```

Wheras the blg-file contains:

```
[0] Config.pm:304> INFO - This is Biber 2.14
[0] Config.pm:307> INFO - Logfile is 'mwe-literatur.blg'
[72] biber-darwin:322> INFO - === So Aug 16, 2020, 11:30:12
[107] Biber.pm:415> INFO - Reading 'mwe-literatur.bcf'
[188] Biber.pm:943> INFO - Found 2 citekeys in bib section 0
[188] Biber.pm:946> DEBUG - The citekeys for section 0 are: schaefer:1967, schaefer:bl
[192] Biber.pm:1016> DEBUG - Adding datalist of type 'entry' with sortingtemplate 'nty', sortingnamekeytemplatename 'global', labelprefix '', uniquenametemplate 'global', labelalphanametemplate 'global' and name 'nty/global//global/global' for section 0
[199] Biber.pm:4256> INFO - Processing section 0
[200] Biber.pm:4378> DEBUG - Looking for directly cited keys: schaefer:1967, schaefer:bl
[200] Utils.pm:75> INFO - Globbing data source 'mybib.bib'
[200] Utils.pm:91> INFO - Globbed data source 'mybib.bib' to mybib.bib
[208] Biber.pm:4455> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'mybib.bib' for section 0
[208] bibtex.pm:177> DEBUG - Caching data for BibTeX format file 'mybib.bib' for section 0
[209] bibtex.pm:1653> INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
[217] bibtex.pm:1471> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'mybib.bib'
[218] bibtex.pm:1578> DEBUG - Cached Text::BibTeX entry for key 'schaefer:bl' from BibTeX file 'mybib.bib'
[218] bibtex.pm:1578> DEBUG - Cached Text::BibTeX entry for key 'schaefer:1967' from BibTeX file 'mybib.bib'
[218] bibtex.pm:235> DEBUG - Text::BibTeX cache keys: schaefer:bl, schaefer:1967
[218] bibtex.pm:236> DEBUG - Wanted keys: schaefer:1967, schaefer:bl
[218] bibtex.pm:239> DEBUG - Looking for key 'schaefer:1967' in Text::BibTeX cache
[218] bibtex.pm:247> DEBUG - Found key 'schaefer:1967' in Text::BibTeX cache
[218] bibtex.pm:803> DEBUG - Source mapping (type=driver, key=schaefer:1967): Deleting field 'day'
[218] bibtex.pm:550> DEBUG - Source mapping (type=driver, key=schaefer:1967): Entry type is 'article' but map wants 'conference', skipping step ...
[218] bibtex.pm:550> DEBUG - Source mapping (type=driver, key=schaefer:1967): Entry type is 'article' but map wants 'electronic', skipping step ...
[218] bibtex.pm:550> DEBUG - Source mapping (type=driver, key=schaefer:1967): Entry type is 'article' but map wants 'www', skipping step ...
[218] bibtex.pm:543> DEBUG - Source mapping (type=driver, key=schaefer:1967): Entry type is 'article' but map wants 'mastersthesis' and step has 'final' set, skipping rest of map ...
[218] bibtex.pm:543> DEBUG - Source mapping (type=driver, key=schaefer:1967): Entry type is 'article' but map wants 'phdthesis' and step has 'final' set, skipping rest of map ...
[218] bibtex.pm:543> DEBUG - Source mapping (type=driver, key=schaefer:1967): Entry type is 'article' but map wants 'techreport' and step has 'final' set, skipping rest of map ...
[219] bibtex.pm:690> DEBUG - Source mapping (type=driver, key=schaefer:1967): No field 'hyphenation', skipping step ...
[219] bibtex.pm:690> DEBUG - Source mapping (type=driver, key=schaefer:1967): No field 'address', skipping step ...
[219] bibtex.pm:690> DEBUG - Source mapping (type=driver, key=schaefer:1967): No field 'school', skipping step ...
[219] bibtex.pm:690> DEBUG - Source mapping (type=driver, key=schaefer:1967): No field 'annote', skipping step ...
[219] bibtex.pm:690> DEBUG - Source mapping (type=driver, key=schaefer:1967): No field 'archiveprefix', skipping step ...
[219] bibtex.pm:690> DEBUG - Source mapping (type=driver, key=schaefer:1967): No field 'primaryclass', skipping step ...
[219] bibtex.pm:690> DEBUG - Source mapping (type=driver, key=schaefer:1967): No field 'key', skipping step ...
[219] bibtex.pm:690> DEBUG - Source mapping (type=driver, key=schaefer:1967): No field 'pdf', skipping step ...
[219] bibtex.pm:904> DEBUG - Creating biber Entry object with key 'schaefer:1967'
```

Comment: Is that on MacOS? If so -> https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/325, https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/298

Comment: The syntax with `biblatex` is `\addbibresource{mybib.bib}`, not `\bibliography{mybib}`.

Comment: My system runs MacOS 10.15.6, MacTeX2020, LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5, biblatex 2019/12/01 v3.14, and biber 2.14. I experience no problems generating the bibliography.

Comment: Just to be clear, the two issues I linked above are about the `darwinlegacy` binaries (`x86_64-darwinlegacy`, MacOSX legacy (10.6-)) I'm not aware of a similar issue for the `x86_64-darwin` binaries (MacOSX current (10.13-)).

Comment: @Bernard `\bibliography{mybib}` is no error, perfectly fine and still supported, but `\addbibresource{mybib.bib}` is definitely *preferred*. (Though I know of a few people who prefer `\bibliography` because it lets them specify multiple files in one go.)

Comment: @moewe: I don't know  where I read, some years ago, it was a error. In any case, compiling with the recommended syntax, I had no problem on my Win 7 system.

Comment: @Bernard Well, it is true that `\addbibresource` is preferred over `\bibliography` and the documentation even goes as far as marking `\bibliography` deprecated. But `\bibliography` still works and is unlikely to be removed from `biblatex` soon (we want to avoid breaking backwards compatibility). The posted code also compiles fine without any changes on Win 10 here. The error message in the `.blg` file suggests something is off with Biber (and since there have been similar reports about the `darwinlegacy` binaries, I'm pretty sure this is not a LaTeX syntax error.)

Comment: @moewe: It was the /var/folders/x2/95kn6jvs4dxbrhq1__t4fgc40000gn/T/par-7567726f68 folder which causes the problem. The issue is now solved. By the way: I am running Mac OS X 10.15.6

Comment: Oh right, it's not the issues I linked above at all. It's https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/543837/35864.

Comment: @moewe Interesting to read and to learn something new.

Comment: Would you be OK with closing this question as a duplicate of the one I linked?

Comment: @moewe this is ok

Comment: If you run into that problem again run `/bin/rm -rf `/Library/TeX/texbin/biber --cache` to clear out the older expansion of biber.