# How to find correctly the .bib file?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, biber, jabref

I have a `.bib` document called `References.bib` saved in the following directory:

```
C:\Users\dvale\Documents\3_References\References.bib
```

This file contains this entry:

```
@Article{Ballot2014,
  author    = {Ballot, Andreas},
  title     = {Diversity of cyanobacteria and cyanotoxins in {Hartbeespoort Dam, South Africa}},
  journal   = {Marine and Freshwater Research},
  year      = {2014},
  volume    = {65},
  number    = {2},
  pages     = {175--189},
  issn      = {1323-1650},
  doi       = {10.1071/mf13153},
}
```

I created a document and cited this reference, however the citation is not appearing, apparently because the `.bib` file was not found. I'm using `biber` as bibliographic tool (if is important this information).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource[location=remote]{C:/Users/dvale/Documentos/3_References/References.bib}
\begin{document}
Example \cite{Ballot2014}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

When I compile the bibliography (F8 in TeXstudio) the following error appears

```
ERROR - Cannot find 'C:/Users/dvale/Documentos/3_References/References.bib'!
```

**EDIT 1:**

I use JabRef to create my `.bib` files with `UTF-8` encoding

The `.blg` file has the following information in the notepad

```
[0] Config.pm:312> INFO - This is Biber 2.15 (beta)
[0] Config.pm:315> INFO - Logfile is 'MWE.blg'
[105] biber-MSWIN64:330> INFO - === 
[127] Biber.pm:415> INFO - Reading 'MWE.bcf'
[234] Biber.pm:952> INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
[251] Biber.pm:4334> INFO - Processing section 0
[267] Biber.pm:4523> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'C:/Users/dvale/Documentos/3_References/References.bib' for section 0
[502] Utils.pm:411> ERROR - Cannot find 'C:/Users/dvale/Documentos/3_References/References.bib'!
[502] Biber.pm:132> INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

Comment: You shouldn't need `[location=remote]` here, but I'm not sure if it does any harm. Do things work if you drop the `[location=remote]` and just say `\addbibresource{C:/Users/dvale/Documentos/3_References/References.bib}`?

Comment: @moewe I just removed `[location=remote]` and the error still appearing

Comment: Mhhh, I just tested this on my machine and everything works fine. Can you please show the full `.blg` file? Also try to compile the file from the command line with `biber --trace <filename>` and show us the `.blg` file.

Comment: @moewe I´m gonna edit the question with this and other informations

Comment: @moewe done, help me please :)

Comment: Mhhh, I see nothing that could explain why the file is not found. Can you type `cd C:\Users\dvale\Documents\3_References` into the command line and then check that `dir` shows your `.bib` file `References.bib`? Since this is a mysterious error, you might as well want to try deleting the cache first and try again: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/543837/35864

Comment: @moewe I ran in the comand line `biber --cache` and then delete the indicated folder. After that, I ran `biber --version` and I got the message `biber version: 2.15 (beta)`. Then I deleted all the auxiliar files from the folder with the MWE and ran it again. Still not working :(

Comment: It is really imperative the absolute path?  (i.e., `c:/Users/.../filename.bib`). If the project is in the same unit that the bib file, is better a relative path, and indeed the best relative path is that pointing to the working directory  (just `filename.bib`)  Sorter, less prone to typing errors and portable if you move the project to another folder, another device or another OS.

Comment: @Fran I use an absolute path because I use those references in almost all the papers, projects, research reports that I write. I think that is more easy manage one `.bib` file than a `.bib` file for every document written. When I put the `.bib` file into the working directory it works, however, the documents already written lose their references

Comment: @DanielValenciaC. Even sharing references, there are not reason to use absolute paths except if you compile from different partitions.  For instance, assuming that each  projects are  subfolders of `Documentos`, is just more handy `../3_References/References.bib` and this way, if you move `Documentos` to a pendrive the  relative path will be always, while the absolute path could be now D:/.. or E:/... , etc. Moreover, for sharing files a better place is the  `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME`  output, that is searchable folder, so you can forget about the route to your references.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the path used for the references.

The path used in the MWE was in Portuguese (language of my notebook)

```
C:/Users/dvale/Documentos/3_References/References.bib
```

But changing Documentos for Documents, the problem disappeared

```
C:/Users/dvale/Documents/3_References/References.bib
```