# “Cannot find file” error when running biber (2)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, biber

I'm writing my thesis using `biblatex` and `biber` for the references. When I compile I get the following error message:

```
ERROR - Cannot find 'C:/Users/dvale/Documentos/3_References/References.bib'!
```

I had a long conversation with @moewe in the comments of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/564682/how-to-find-correctly-the-bib-file) question, traying to solve this issue. Apparently anything is wrong, but the MWE still not working in my computer. Does anyone else have any information to help me fix this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource[location=remote]{C:/Users/dvale/Documentos/3_References/References.bib}
\begin{document}
Example \cite{Ballot2014}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Informations:

The `.bib` file was created with JabRef with `UTF-8` encoding

The `.bib` file has 362 entries

The `.bib` file size is 185 KB

I'm using TeXstudio

The default bibliographic tool is `biber`

The default compiler is `pdflatex`

When I put the `.bib` file into the working directory, the MWE run perfectly

```
#With References.bib into the MWE working directory
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
\begin{document}
Example \cite{Ballot2014}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I already tried to clear the `biber` cache

This problem starts when I change my notebook

I really need to use a single bib file for all my documents, instead of having a bib file for each document, since the references are all about the same subject and I already have written documents that lose their references.

Comment: Not a solution, but perhaps a workaround. I keep my local `texmf` folder in Dropbox and use  symbolic links on each machine to it so that it is available to any machine I use.

Comment: why location = remote?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That was my last attempt to solve the problem. I already tried without `[location = remote]`, I also tried to change the path to `../3_References/References.bib`, but none of my attempts worked. I'm gonna update the question with some pictures showing things that I think that may help

Comment: Show a screenshot of the folder address and the bib-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I found the error. Was really the path. I wrote `C:/Users/dvale/Documentos/3_References/References.bib` and change `Documentos` for `Documents` and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the path used for the references.

The path used in the MWE was in Portuguese (language of my notebook)

```
C:/Users/dvale/Documentos/3_References/References.bib
```

But changing Documentos for Documents, the problem disappeared

```
C:/Users/dvale/Documents/3_References/References.bib
```