# Bibtex vs. biber unstable behaviour

Tags: bibtex, biber, latexmk

Some strange problem occurred to me, when writing a report. I found some similar questions but none of the solutions work for me. Until today, my bibliography worked fine, today everything crashed. I was working with `biber` but I can not get it working anymore, so I had to switch to `bibtex` now. Here is my MWE:

main.tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber, % or bibtex
    style=phys,
    sorting=none,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

Hi there, this is me.~\cite{Nobody06}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and the references.bib:

```
@misc{ Nobody06,
author = "Nobody Jr",
title = "My Article",
year = "2006" }
```

I am using VScode and its recipes (pdflatex-bibtex-pdflatex x2 or latexmk). When using `biber` as a backend I get `undefined references` error, while when using `bibtex` I just get `Using fall-back BibTeX(8) backend: (biblatex) functionality may be reduced/unavailable.` warning but it compiles successfully.

**The strangest thing is that both options works fine on overleaf.**

When I try to compile it by hand in the command line `pdflatex main` and then `biblatex main` I still get `undefined references`. When doing `biber main` I get `Cannot find 'main.bcf'`, so I am wondering which is the correct combination?

Relevant versions:

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020)
BibTeX 0.99d (TeX Live 2020) kpathsea version 6.3.2
biber version: 2.15
```

Comment: `biber main` should be the right call. Do you have a main.bcf and is it where biber is looking for it?

Comment: No, this is the problem. I assumed that the first `pdflatex main` call should produce the .bcf file. Am I mistaken? All of the commands are done in root folder, where both main.tex and references.bib are placed.

Comment: is the resulting pdf and the log-file in the root folder too?

Comment: Yes it is. Hmm, now by setting `biber` as backend and running `pdflatex main` and then  `biber main`, biber runs without troubles but when running `pdflatex` twice there are still undefined references and there is a bold name of the reference in the pdf file.

Comment: If biber run, there should be a blg-file. Show it.

Comment: ```
[0] Config.pm:312> INFO - This is Biber 2.15
[0] Config.pm:315> INFO - Logfile is 'main.blg'
[88] biber-darwin:330> INFO - === Fri Feb 26, 2021, 15:16:17
[108] Biber.pm:415> INFO - Reading 'main.bcf'
[216] Biber.pm:952> INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
[233] Biber.pm:4334> INFO - Processing section 0
[246] Biber.pm:4523> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'references.bib' for section 0
[247] bibtex.pm:1682> INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
[250] bibtex.pm:1494> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'references.bib'
```

Comment: This looks incomplete. Run on a command line `biber --cache` . This will report a file, delete it and try again. biber will then recreate its cache.

Comment: Great, this solved the problem, thank you very much! Can you write this as an answer?
Can you just elaborate on what/why was the problem?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/543837/35864. Out of curiosity: Are you on a Mac?

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Yes, I am on a mac.

Comment: Interesting, I've heard it suggested that there are some issues with the Biber cache on Macs: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/368. Maybe the OS has become more protective of the temp directory or does some more aggressive cleanup?