# Biber/Biblatex suddenly error with citation

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I am very new to latex so I don't really know how any of this works, but i got someone to help me with biber/biblatex (i do not know the difference?) and it has been working fine for weeks, but today when i tried to compile with biber (i use TeXworks) i got the message

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.14
INFO - Logfile is 'BAMaiken20052021.blg'
INFO - Reading 'BAMaiken20052021.bcf'
INFO - Found 12 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Globbing data source 'Maikenlitteratur.bib'
INFO - Globbed data source 'Maikenlitteratur.bib' to Maikenlitteratur.bib
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'Maikenlitteratur.bib' for section 0
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'Maikenlitteratur.bib'
```

and none of my citations work.

I looked at the .bib file but i think it looks fine.
I dont know what else to do.

Comment: try to delete the biber cache. Call `biber --cache` to find where it is.

Comment: How do i do that? Where should i write biber --cache ?

Comment: in command line or terminal.

Comment: Now it says where they are - how do i delete them? (Sorry i really do not know anything about this)

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/543837/35864.

Comment: Ah i see! Thank you to both of you! Edit: It worked perfectly!