# Error with Biblatex using Biber

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, bibdesk, bibliographystyle

When I try to compile my document (see MWE below) it doesn't use the numeric style and the following message is produced in the prompt of TeXstudio:

```
Prozess gestartet: biber "MWE_05"

INFO - This is Biber 2.16
INFO - Logfile is 'MWE_05.blg'
INFO - Reading 'MWE_05.bcf'
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file '../../shared/Quellen/Test.bib' for section 0
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
INFO - Found BibTeX data source '../../shared/Quellen/Test.bib'
Prozess endete mit Fehler(n)
```

I am a little puzzled too because it tells me something about BibTeX even though I use BibLaTeX?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[%
backend=biber,
bibencoding=utf8,
style=numeric, % numeric
%citestyle=numeric,
sorting=none
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{../../shared/Quellen/Test.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{Test}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

.bib file:

```
%% This BibTeX bibliography file was created using BibDesk.
%% https://bibdesk.sourceforge.io/

%% Created for user at 2021-06-28 13:04:24 +0200 


%% Saved with string encoding Unicode (UTF-8) 



@book{Test,
    author = {Autor Nachname},
    date-added = {2021-06-28 13:03:30 +0200},
    date-modified = {2021-06-28 13:04:05 +0200},
    publisher = {Test Verlag},
    title = {Test Titel},
    year = {2021}}
```

for BibDesk I closed the program, downloaded the file for BibLaTeX and saved it as stated [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/bibdesk/wiki/Tips_and_Tricks/) under "BibLateX Types and Fields" (no fields in the program's GUI changed though).

Comment: when the biber log stops like this, it often indicates a faulty cache. Run `biber --cache` on a terminal to get the location, delete the cache and then try again. biber will then unpack itself anew.

Comment: The data format that `biblatex` is using is the same format as `bibtex` has used like forever. You can see that it mentions a `.bib` file.

Comment: this was the response I got from running the cache command @UlrikeFischer: 
```
INFO - This is Biber 2.16
INFO - Logfile is 'cache.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find 'cache.bcf'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

Comment: did you use the two hyphens before cache?

Comment: yes I used them in the command

Comment: Do I have to change directories before I use that command as I have used it directly after opening the Terminal (macOS)?

Comment: sorry but your output looks as if you entered `biber cache` and not `biber --cache`.

Comment: I am sorry, there was a space too much after both hyphens (there should be none), now I got a location. Do I have to delete all files in this directory or just some specific ones?

Comment: you can delete the whole directory.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/543837/35864. It is a known issue that the Biber cache gets corrupted on Mac OS from time to time. Alas it appears to be a very tricky issue to investigate, so I don't think a fix is easy to come by.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, would you please write your solution as an answer, so that I can mark this post as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when the biber log stops like this, it often indicates a faulty cache. Run

```
 biber --cache
```

on a terminal to get the location, delete the cache and then try again. biber will then unpack itself anew. –