# Empty bibliography with biblatex and biber

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

In my document, the bib-related code are:

```
% in the preamble
\usepackage[
  style=alphabetic,
  giveninits = true,
  doi = false,
  isbn = false,
  defernumbers = true,
]{biblatex}
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=address, null]
      \step[fieldset=location, null]
    }
  }
}
\addbibresource{duality.bib}
```

and

```
% in the document
\section*{References}
% \nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
```

Everything works fine two days ago, but today when I recompile the document the bibliography section becomes empty, and the command `\cite{<label>}` would simply print as `[<label>]` in the document.

I tried to clear all the auxiliary files and recompile but there are always:

```
There were undefined references.

Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)  duality-outline
(biblatex)  and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

Empty bibliography.

...
```

And even if I rerun `biber` it is still the same. The biber info messages show the following:

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.19
INFO - Logfile is '/Users/.../duality-outline.blg'
INFO - Reading '/Users/.../duality-outline.bcf'
INFO - Using all citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex file 'duality.bib' for section 0
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
INFO - Found BibTeX data source '/Users/.../duality.bib'
```

When using `latexmk` the `.blg` file looks similar:

```
[0] Config.pm:307> INFO - This is Biber 2.19
[0] Config.pm:310> INFO - Logfile is 'duality-outline.blg'
[39] biber-darwin:340> INFO - === Mon Nov 27, 2023, 09:35:44
[51] Biber.pm:419> INFO - Reading 'duality-outline.bcf'
[96] Biber.pm:976> INFO - Using all citekeys in bib section 0
[103] Biber.pm:4419> INFO - Processing section 0
[113] Biber.pm:4610> INFO - Looking for bibtex file 'duality.bib' for section 0
[114] bibtex.pm:1713> INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
[118] bibtex.pm:1519> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'duality.bib'
```

and with `latexmk` it is even worse, even the usual references break and would be shown as `??`.

Do you have any clue why this might happen?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/611063/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for this! Clear the cache folder and retry solves the issue.