# Bib Section 0 problem with citation

Tags: biblatex

I am currently writing up a report with LaTex, using Texstudio 3.0.1, compiled with Qt 5.15.0, and I am running up to a problem with bibtex. Previously, I could just open up the tex file and just build it, but occasionally, like now, the bibliography section will run into a problem, and cannot find any citation key. When running Biber, the following message is seen:

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.14
INFO - Logfile is 'EE_draft.blg'
INFO - Reading 'EE_draft.bcf'
INFO - Found 8 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Globbing data source 'EESources.bib'
INFO - Globbed data source 'EESources.bib' to EESources.bib
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'EESources.bib' for section 0
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'EESources.bib'

Process exited with error(s)
```

Below is a sample code from the Tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{C{#1}}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\addbibresource{EESources.bib}

\title{A super cool title}
\author{Je-Yu (Leo) Chou}
\date{April 2021}

\begin{document}
\maketitle 

\section{Introduction}
This is where I write and cite \parencite{pruim2005complexity}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and the corresponding entry in bibtex

```
@book{pruim2005complexity,
  title={Complexity Theory: Exploring the Limits of Efficient Algorithms},
  author={Pruim, R. and Wegener, I.},
  isbn={9783540210450},
  lccn={2005920530},
  url={https://books.google.com/books?id=1fo7\_KoFUPsC},
  year={2005},
  publisher={Springer Berlin Heidelberg}
}
```

And then the citation would not show up (log file says that the citation key is undefined). Has anyone run into this problem before? Sometimes this resolves, and sometimes it works for some but not others, so I'm very confused at this point. Any help is appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: If it doesn't work, but the `.blg` looks like this, it's probably a corrupted Biber cache. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/543837/35864. Delete the cache as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864 and then rerun Biber. The next Biber run will take much longer than usual. Do not stop the run or kill the process, wait for Biber to finish. It will have to unpack the cache again.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you should not have to LaTeX-escape characters like `_` in the URL field. `url={https://books.google.com/books?id=1fo7\_KoFUPsC},` is wrong. `url={https://books.google.com/books?id=1fo7_KoFUPsC},` will work just as well. `publisher={Springer Berlin Heidelberg}` could be `publisher={Springer}, location = { Berlin and Heidelberg},`. Normally location and publisher name are separated.

Comment: Just to make sure, I ran the code as shown and it compiles fine for me (the URL comes out as `https://books.google.com/books?id=1fo7%5C_KoFUPsC`, which is wrong, but that is clearly not a compile error), so there is nothing wrong with the code that would stop it from compiling. This makes the Biber cache error definitely the most likely explanation why things go wrong.

Comment: Voted to close as duplicate of the Biber cache issue, since that is the most likely explanation in absence of feedback.