# Glossary missing entries

Tags: table-of-contents, glossaries-extra

My thesis' table of contents shows that the glossary of symbols starts on page 61 and that the following chapter, the index, starts on page 65.

[image: The glossary and the index in the table of contents]

The glossary indeed starts on page 61, but is missing many entries.

[image: First page of glossary]

And the index starts on page 63, contrary to what the table of contents says.

[image: First page of index]

My document starts thus:

```
\documentclass[Bibliography=totoc,index=totoc]{scrbook}
```

I use `glossaries-extra` in the preamble thus:

```
\usepackage[automake,sort=use]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries
```

My document ends thus:

```
\setglossarypreamble{\emph{The symbols are listed in the order their definitions occur in the document.}}
\printglossary[title={Glossary of Symbols}]
\printindex
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
```

I compile my code with `arara` thus:

```
% arara: clean: { extensions: [aux, bbl, bcf, blg, glg, glo, gls, idx, ilg, ind, ist, log, out, run.xml, slnc, tex~, toc] }
% arara: lualatex
% arara: biber
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: lualatex
% arara: lualatex
```

Why is the glossary missing entries, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You should add a minimal example that shows the issue. How can we guess what you're doing?

Comment: @egreg: I would gladly, but I don't see how it's possible in this case. Hopefully someone has encountered a similar issue in the past and can suggest a solution, or else someone can help me debug the issue by asking me to provide information from the log or other files.

Answer (score 0):

I added the line

```
% arara: makeglossaries
```

between the last pair of

```
% arara: lualatex
```

and now the glossary prints correctly.

I should add that this is how my arara sequence was originally, but then [David Carlisle suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610823/arara-fails-on-biber-but-standalone-biber-doesnt-fail#comment1527719_610823) that my arara sequence had redundancies, so I cut it down to

```
% arara: clean: { extensions: [aux, bbl, bcf, blg, glg, glo, gls, idx, ilg, ind, ist, log, out, run.xml, slnc, tex~, toc] }
% arara: lualatex
% arara: biber
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: lualatex
```

But then I got warnings in the log file asking me to run `latex` once more, so I changed my arara sequence to the one mentioned in my original post. But evidently this too was not enough, and my original sequence which David Carlisle thought was off, was correct, namely

```
% arara: lualatex
% arara: biber
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: lualatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: lualatex
```