# Unable to run biber in vscode

Tags: biblatex, biber, vscode

I always use vscode to run LaTeX and my codes of recipe in settings.json are

```
"latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
                 {
                   "name": "xelatex",
                   "tools": [
                     "xelatex"
                   ]
                 },
                 {
                   "name": "xe*2",
                   "tools": [
                     "xelatex",
                     "xelatex"
                   ]
                 },
                 {
                   "name": "xelatex -> biber-> xelatex*2",
                   "tools": [
                     "xelatex",
                     "biber",
                     "xelatex",
                     "xelatex"
                   ]
                 }
               ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
                 {
                   "name": "latexmk",
                   "command": "latexmk",
                   "args": [
                     "-synctex=1",
                     "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                     "-file-line-error",
                     "-pdf",
                     "%DOC%"
                   ]
                 },
                 {
                   "name": "xelatex",
                   "command": "xelatex",
                   "args": [
                     "-synctex=1",
                     "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                     "-file-line-error",
                     "%DOC%"
                   ]
                 },
                 {
                  "name": "biber",
                  "command": "biber",
                  "args": [
                      "%DOCFILE%"
                  ]
                }
                ]
```

and I use the package Biblatex by

`\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}`

However, after the LaTeX workshop update this morning, every time I run the file, it tells me that
**Recipe terminated with error. Retry building the project.**
If I change biber back to bibtex, then it works well.
I don't know why this happens and how to deal with this problem.

The content of the file `.blg` is

```
[0] Config.pm:311> INFO - This is Biber 2.16
[0] Config.pm:314> INFO - Logfile is 'F4.blg'
[60] biber-darwin:340> INFO - === Tue Nov 16, 2021, 14:34:37
[72] Biber.pm:415> INFO - Reading 'F4.bcf'
[154] Biber.pm:952> INFO - Found 20 citekeys in bib section 0
[166] Biber.pm:4340> INFO - Processing section 0
[174] Biber.pm:4531> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'bibliography.bib' for section 0
[175] bibtex.pm:1689> INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
[190] bibtex.pm:1494> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'bibliography.bib'
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: what is the argument being passed to biber? also if there was an error it will be recorded in the latex or biber log files, what error messages do you see?

Comment: It shows that ```[14:00:54]Recipe step 2: biber, F4
[14:00:54] Recipe step env: undefined
[14:00:54] cwd: /Users/shanyi/Desktop/LaTeX/F4 thesis
[14:00:54] LaTeX build process spawned. PID: 29104.
[14:00:55] Recipe returns with error: 2/null. PID: 29104. message: ```

Comment: If Biber ran, there should be a `.blg` file somewhere. (Despite what Windows might say, the `.blg` file is a simple text file, you can open with your favourite text editor.) Please post the full contents of the `.blg` file into your question (it should not be too long).

Comment: Thanks, I post the contents of ```.blg``` into the question.

Comment: This is not the `.blg` of a successfully Biber run. If the file stops prematurely like this, this is usually caused by a broken cache. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/543837/35864 for some background. Delete the Biber cache as explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864 and recompile (note that the next Biber run after deleting the cache might take *much* longer than usual: do not stop the run or start a new Biber run, wait for Biber to unpack itself into the cache).

Comment: Thank you meowe! I solve the problem as you said.