# Biber no longer compiles - no obvious error message

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am writing my master thesis using Texmaker and literally out of the blue, after like 1000 compilations where everything worked, this error appears. Does anyone know what this means and how to fix it?

```
Process started

INFO - This is Biber 2.16
INFO - Logfile is 'thesis.blg'
INFO - Reading 'thesis.bcf'
INFO - Using all citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'thesisreferences.bib' for section 0
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'thesisreferences.bib'

Process exited with error(s)
```

I am using `biblatex` and this is my related code.

```
...
\usepackage[firstinits=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{thesisreferences.bib}

\begin{document}

...


\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a [minimal (non-)working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). Without it, we can only guess what the problem is.

Comment: Your Biber cache is probably corrupted. Apparently this happens from time to time on some systems (presumably due to clean up of the temp directory, where the cache lives). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/543837/35864. Find the cache directory as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864, delete it and re-run Biber. This re-run might take much longer than a usual Biber run. Just wait for it to finish, do not abort the run or start another one. Biber will then hopefully unpack properly again.

Comment: Thank you very much! The Biber cache was corrupted. After I cleared the cache, everything worked again.