# Biblatex can't find references

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

It seems like `BibLaTeX` is now unable to find my citations, and no bibliography is printed. The `References.bib` file is not empty.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
\begin{document}

Some text.

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I keep getting the following warning:

> LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 13.
>
> [1{/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
> (./Document.aux)
>
> LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
>
> Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
> (biblatex)                Document
> (biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

EDIT: Here is also the log copied from the `.blg` file:

```
[0] Config.pm:307> INFO - This is Biber 2.17
[0] Config.pm:310> INFO - Logfile is 'Document.blg'
[53] biber-darwin:340> INFO - === Sat Jun 11, 2022, 18:52:24
[65] Biber.pm:418> INFO - Reading 'Document.bcf'
[132] Biber.pm:969> INFO - Using all citekeys in bib section 0
[143] Biber.pm:4383> INFO - Processing section 0
[151] Biber.pm:4574> INFO - Looking for bibtex file 'References.bib' for section 0
[151] bibtex.pm:1713> INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
[155] bibtex.pm:1518> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'References.bib'
```

Comment: Did you run biber between latex runs?

Comment: Yes multiple times. Does my code run fine for you?

Comment: show the log you get from biber, does it show any error?

Comment: we can not run the code as you have not posted a bib file.

Comment: The relevant log output lives in the `.blg` file. It should be short enough that it can be shared in the question in its entirety.

Comment: Thanks, I added the content of the `.blg` file to the original question.

Comment: The `.blg` may appear fine at first glance, but ends prematurely. Often this is caused by a broken cache. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/543837/35864. Delete the cache as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864. Then recompile. Note that the next Biber run after deleting the cache may take *much* longer than usual. Wait for it to finish, do not try to interrupt the run or start Biber a second time.

Comment: Clearing the cache did the trick, thank you!