# biber aborts with no message

Tags: biblatex

I am running Fedora 35:

```
Linux nyx 5.18.16-602.inttf.fc36.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Aug 5 08:54:23 EDT 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have a large bibliography (~1150 entries) in Zotero which I can export as a biblatex file using betterbiblatex.

When I try to use LaTeX to print the bibliography Biber quits:

```
ross@nyx Articles]$ biber -D --validate_datamodel testBiblatex32
INFO - This is Biber 2.17
INFO - Logfile is 'testBiblatex32.blg'
INFO - DEBUG mode: all messages are logged to 'testBiblatex32.blg'
INFO - Reading 'testBiblatex32.bcf'
INFO - Using all citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex file 'A30.bib' for section 0
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "aug"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "dec"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "may"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "jun"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "mar"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "nov"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "sep"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "apr"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "jul"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "jan"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "feb"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "oct"
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'A30.bib'
free(): invalid next size (fast)
Aborted (core dumped)
[ross@nyx Articles]$
```

The `.blg` file is huge, but seems to provide no information about what is wrong with the `.bib` file. Is it the case that Biber regards `.bib` like `.xml` so that any error in the `.bib` file causes the running program (Biber) to fail with no message?

My Biber cache is in `/tmp` and removing those files does not help.

I like to think I'm pretty well versed in LaTeX, but this has me stumped.

Comment: Do you only get the error on this large file or can you reproduce the issue also with more reasonably sized `.bib` files like `biblatex-examples.bib`? Normally weird issues without clear error messages are caused by a bad cache (see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/543837/35864), but if you've already cleaned up your cache it is unlikely this should be the issue again (unless your OS aggressively cleans out the `/tmp` directory or has some very strict security settings there). ...

Comment: ... I have no idea where it actually comes from, but the `free(): invalid next size (fast)` looks like a memory issue to me. Maybe you've hit some limit with that large a file.

Comment: How large is the file? Any C-like memory error would be coming from the `btparse` library that `biber` uses which usually indicates some edge-case of malformation in the `.bib` file. It would also be useful to have the `.bib` posted somewhere for reproduction. Does it happen without the datamodel validation option?