Undefined Citations using biblatex
I am aware that there are many answers regarding undefined citations but I have looked at them and my problem still remains. I have a sample tex file 'test.tex':
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0.89in, right=1.59in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}%margins and paper size
\usepackage[sorting=none,maxnames=3,firstinits=true,doi=false,url=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}

% Adjust the spacing between bibliography entries
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

\newpage

\section{Introduction}
\cite{citation}

\printbibliography

\end{document}

where im using biblatex with the corresponding bib file 'test.bib'
@book{citation,
  title={Test},
  author={John Smith},
  booktitle={Contemporary Concepts of Condensed Matter Science},
  volume={6},
  pages={3--34},
  year={2013},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

As I understand it, the correct compilation sequence is
latex test
biber test
latex test
latex test

but when I do this I get the following error:
James@James-Laptop test % latex test
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric.cbx)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)

Package biblatex Warning: 'firstinits' option is deprecated.
(biblatex)                Please use 'giveninits' instead.

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)))
(./test.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)
(./test.bbl)

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'citation' on page 1 undefined on input line 11.

[1]

LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 16.

[2] (./test.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                test
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

 )
Output written on test.dvi (2 pages, 504 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
James@James-Laptop test % 

where it wants me to try the sequence again. I have been trying to fix this for hours and so I don't think this is the solution. I am on Mac Sonoma 14.4.1 and have tried entirely uninstalling texlive and then reinstalling from MacTex. Please could someone help I am entirely lost. Apologies in advance if I am missing something obvious but I have checked many other answers so I believe that this may be an issue that has not been covered here before.
Additionall information: the pdf looks like this

How are you running biber?

Hi,I just run 'biber test' in the terminal. This is 'test.blg'
[0] Config.pm:307> INFO - This is Biber 2.19 [0] Config.pm:310> INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg' [64] biber-darwin:340> INFO - === Sun May  5, 2024, 17:33:19 [79] Biber.pm:419> INFO - Reading 'test.bcf' [157] Biber.pm:979> INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0 [171] Biber.pm:4419> INFO - Processing section 0 [181] Biber.pm:4610> INFO - Looking for bibtex file 'test.bib' for section 0 [182] bibtex.pm:1713> INFO - LaTeX decoding ... [184] bibtex.pm:1519> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'test.bib'

What does the rest of the .blg say?

Delete the Biber cache: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/543837/35864.

@moewe this worked thank you so much!
