Bibtex or biber will not compile after updating TexShop for macOS
I use TexShop for macOS to create/edit my thesis document. I use Zotero (v7.0.7) to produce the .bib file, the first line of the .tex file says % !BIB program = biber to make sure that compiled is using biber. Later in the preamble I use the commands \usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex} and \addbibresource{refLibrary.bib}. For some reason the .bib must be open in Bibdesk (v1.9.5) when compiling the .tex file in TexShop or it won't work.
That set-up was working the last 2 years but a few days ago, the console started returning 340 warnings all about the date formatting in my references when I ran the bibtex typeset. A bunch of references no longer had a date in the final .pdf file. They were left with just empty parentheses. I have no idea where this first issue came from as the data in Zotero didn't change, but in response I updated the applications to the latest versions (TexShop=v5.46, Zotero=v7.0.7, Bibdesk=v1.9.5) hoping the bug would be patched.
Now, bibtex does not run whatsoever. The console remains blank and doesn't give any errors. It's almost as if the typset button doesn't work for bibtex. I can run pdflatex just fine. And pdflatexmk runs too, but still no bibliography, it gives the message;
Latexmk: Summary of warnings from last run of *latex:
 Latex failed to resolve 256 reference (s)
 Latex failed to resolve 615 citation (s)
 Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
 biber Portfolio: Command for 'biber Portfolio' gave return code 0.0234375

I can't find any info about that return code. I have tried the Tex Live Utility (v1.54) but that gives me loads of issues too. When I first open the app a pop-up says:

Unable to find a valid update server. Either a network problem exists or the TeX Live version on the server does not match. If this problem persists on further attempts, you may need to try a different repository.

I click ok, and under the packages tab, it will show me all the packages including biber, biblatex-cheatsheet, biblatex-readbbl, and ecobiblatex. Reinstalling these packages fails though. Under 'updates' tab it says "listing failed". If refresh I get another pop-up message;

Repository URL has a newer TeX Live version. Your TeX Live version is 2022, but your default repository URL appears to be for TeX Live 2024. You need to manually upgrade to a newer version of TeX Live, as there will be no further updates for your version.

If I click upgrade, the browser opens https://tug.org/mactex/ but that website only has the option to download the entire MacTex installation at 5.7 Gb which seems crazy. I only want to fix the biber package.
-------- EDIT: UPDATE 17-10-2024 --------
Ok so following advice in the comments, I downloaded and reinstalled MacTeX. When I tried to typset bibtex I got a message that I needed a program called "Command Line Developer Tools". I downloaded and install that too. Then the TexShop console gave me this error message:
INFO - This is Biber 2.19
INFO - Logfile is 'Portfolio.blg'
INFO - Reading 'Portfolio.bcf'
ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.8, expected version 3.10.
This means that your biber (2.19) and biblatex (3.17) versions are incompatible.
See compat matrix in biblatex or biber PDF documentation.
INFO - ERRORS: 1

Next I opened Tex Live Utility (2024 version) and updated biber and bibtex packages. But now I am back to the same situation as before where nothing happens when I typset bibtex and when I typset pdflatexmk I get the response Command for 'biber Portfolio' gave return code 0.0234375. I have no idea what to do... I cannot find any info about this 0.0234375 error code anywhere.
-------- EDIT: UPDATE 19-10-2024 --------
To make things clear: I have now gone and updated basically everything to the latest version that I can update: MaxTeX, TexShop, Zotero, Tex Live Utility, all packages within Tex Live Utility (I'm running macOS sequioa 15.0.1) but the problem still  persists :(
In repsonse to @cfr I have created a new document as simple as possible. The files from this simple example are available from my google-drive: log file and tex file and bib file. I typeset pdflatex once, then typeset bibtex and console returned the following message. The only other thing I noticed is that in /Users/username/Library/TeXShop/Engines there is no bibtex engine, is there supposed one ??
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refLibrary.bib}

\begin{document}
    \begin{refsection}
    Hello world \cite{metropolis_monte_1949}.
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
    \end{refsection}
\end{document}

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2024)
The top-level auxiliary file: main.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file main.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file main.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file main.aux
(There were 3 error messages)


Welcome to TeX.SE! It seems you have to upgrade to the current TeX Live version 2024 ...

I'm willing to try that, is there any way to update TeX Live without downloading & reinstalling the entire 6Gy MacTex installation?

I downloaded and installed that MacTeX.pkg file. Now when I typset using bibtex now I get an error saying "/Library/TeX/texbin/biber: Command Line Tools are not installed - run 'xcode-select --install' to install (errno=17)". I pasted that command into terminal and app called "Install Command Line Developer Tools" opened. It's predicting over 50 hours to download the new thing... still no end in sight

Once you've installed the MacTeX2024 distribution, you can delete the TeXLive2022 distribution. Unless your harddisk is 99% full at the moment, I can't see much of a downside to making life easy for yourself by simply downloading and installing the full MacTeX2024 distribution. Or do you just prefer pursuing the "Install command line developer tools" route? Of course, if your harddisk really is 99% or more full at the moment, you probably have other, far more pressing problems in life to contend with...

@Mico I took the OP to mean that the demand for CLTs popped up after installing the 6G MacTeX pkg. but I would think that if those are required for 2024, they would've been needed for 2022, as well, so it sounds odd. but 50 hours to download command line developer tools seems ... excessive? I've no idea what apple put in there these days, but I could install an OS many. many times over and all of TeX Live in significantly less than 50 hours. the only way I can think it would take that long would be really, really awful internet connection.

@cfr - It's quite possible that I've misunderstood what the OP has tried to do. My impression (which I admit may be incorrect!) was that they had tried to install BasicTeX, which is less than 100 MBy in size, and were now stuck with having to add various utilities by hand. Let's see if the OP provides more information. If I was wrong, I'm sorry to have impugned the OP.

@cfr see my edit to the main post, but I originally installed MacTeX a back in 2022 and then didnt do anyhting to it. I just used the TexShop and bibdesk that came along with that installation

Delete the .aux, .bbl, .bcf files and recompile with LaTeX and Biber (LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX). The incompatibility message should be gone.

@moewe i tried that and it hasnt worked unfortunately

it isn't clear whether you actually installed MacTeX 2024 and then used the utility to update everything or whether you have tried to cherry-pick certain updates. the latter won't work. in particular, updating biber without updating biblatex - not bibtex - won't work. and updating biblatex without updating latex is asking for trouble, as is updating latex without updating the packages which depend on it ....

the original error could be caused by changes outside MacTeX/Zotero. for example, have you updated OS X? MacTeX uses OS X's installation of perl, for example, and biber depends on perl. so an OS update could easily have implications for biber. if you haven't bitten the bullet and installed MacTeX 2024, that's what you need to do. if you have, you should not have conflicting versions of biber and biblatex, so please post the log from a minimal example e.g. a document with a single citation which just loads biblatex.

@cfr thanks for the reply. i made a simple test case, see my edit under 'update 19-10-2024 '

The issue in your 19-10-2024 update is straightforward, you should be running biber with biblatex and you are instead running bibtex.  See Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations.

@dai-bowen I have gone into the TexShop preferences page and changed the bibtex engine from 'Bibex' to 'Biblatex' but my console still remains blank when i typset. I really don't understand what's going on tbh. the drop-down menu in the GUI still says 'bibtex' no matter what engine i choose in preferences

Beyond pointing you to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154778/106162, I don't know TeXShop enough to help further. Your document needs biber to compile and it's being run with bibtex right now, so the bibliography is not expected to work. If you can run biber on your document the command line you should be able to verify that this is just an editor configuration issue.

@dai-bowen thanks for the suggestion! I ran biber portfolio in terminal and it failed, but the response is interesting cos it finally gave me something to work with. I think Zotero isn't encoding the .bib file correctly. Last 3 lines that Terminal spat out were;INFO - Looking for bibtex file 'refLibrary.bib' for section 1 then INFO - LaTeX decoding ... and zsh: abort      biber portfolio.

Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/543837/35864. There is an intermittent issue on the mac where Biber's cache would get corrupted. You have to delete it and recompile (the next run will take much longer than usual, do not interrupt it.)

I figured it out eventually, the problem was Zotero (v7.0.8):

A comment suggested to try typesetting the document using the command line (Terminal) instead of TexShop application. This also failed. Crucially tho Terminal did not simply remain blank like the TexShop console.
I ran biber portfolio and Terminal would begin as normal. Immediately after the line INFO - LaTeX decoding ... the zsh shell would abort.
This was the key. This made me realise the .bib file was the problem.
I tried re-exporting my Zotero library every which way (UTF-8, UTF-8 without BOM, bibtex, biblatex, etc) but it failed to decode every time.
Then I installed a plugin for Zotero called Better Bibtex. I chosen the 'Better BibLaTex' format and this simply worked first time.
Better BibLaTex has different cite keys than the .bib file produced by Zotero itself so I had to manually change every citation in my thesis (this took me hours! my thesis is like 500 pages)
All apps/packages are updated to the latest version so I think Zotero (v7.0.8) definitely a bug with how it exports a library to Bibtex/Biblatex.

P.S. People have pointed out that I'm using mismatched components... the TexShop engine is 'bibtex', reference library from Better Bibtex is 'BibLaTex', and .tex file itself specifies 'biber'. I dunno why but that just works.

This sounds very strange, I would guess you have something very unconventional in an entry that Better Bibtex is processing differently. You might be able to pin it down by selecting entries, generating bib files and bisecting. Or calling biber with the debug flag might hint further.

Better Bibtex can be configured to match the Zotero key style with zotero.clean (https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/citing/)

On the postscript, compiling biblatex (unless loaded with the less capable, not recommended (and possibly deprecated?) backend=bibtex option) requires biber, but editors don't necessarily have separate bibtex and biber buttons, so sometimes the easiest way to set this in editors is to change the settings so that when bibtex is called from the interface it will run biber, this is exactly what the first part of this answer appears to suggest for TeXShop.

thanks for the reply. i did try to clean up the references in Zotero when i was troubleshooting but i've accumulated hundreds of entries so going thru them manually to check all fields for a non-unicode character seemed impossible and i quickly gave up. Luckily BetterBibtex works.

Sure, but crashing biber (esp. if resolvable with better bibtex) should be quite a niche case, and it should be feasible to pin down the problematic entries by generating a bib file with the first half of your citations, compiling that and depending whether it errors (problem in first half) or not (problem in second half) trying the first or third quarter and so on bisecting until you identify a single problematic reference which is then feasible to examine carefully.

@DaiBowen i think i found the offending entry. I had referenced a paper from poland and the last author's name ended in ł. This non-english character had been typed as \l in the name field in Zotero. I also found another entry which used this character in the title: ☆ (yes it was a genuine peer-reviewed scientific paper). Also the random warnings about date formatting is a known issue i guess, it can be solved in the future by deleting the biber cache: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140814/biblatex-biber-fails-with-a-strange-error-about-missing-recode-data-xml-file
