# Biber exiting with error code 2 but no error messages

Tags: bibtex, biber

I get the following output (terminal output and `blg` log file) from running `biber build/essay`. It fails with error code 2 but doesn't give any error message... how helpful!

```
[0] Config.pm:311> INFO - This is Biber 2.16
[0] Config.pm:314> INFO - Logfile is 'build/essay.blg'
[120] biber-darwin:340> INFO - === Mon Jan 18, 2021, 04:53:13
[148] Biber.pm:415> INFO - Reading 'build/essay.bcf'
[337] Biber.pm:949> INFO - Using all citekeys in bib section 0
[365] Biber.pm:4340> INFO - Processing section 0
[385] Biber.pm:4531> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'essay.bib' for section 0
[388] bibtex.pm:1689> INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
[403] bibtex.pm:1494> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'essay.bib'
```

Things used to run fine, but randomly stopped working.

Here's my (sample) [`essay.bib` file](https://gist.github.com/69ad53f0d87fd57748052790e43854af).

### Update

It seems like the biber run passes when I remmove all numeric fields from the file (e.g., `year`, `volume`, `number`)... odd!

Comment: Biber 2.16, TeX Live 2020, for anyone curious.

Comment: your bib works fine for me (on windows). Run `biber --cache` to get the cache location and delete it.  Then try again, biber will then unpack itself anew. This sometimes helps.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you, that did the trick! I thought deleting `build/` would be enough, but evidently not. If you would like to add this as a brief answer, I will immediately upvote and accept.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/543837/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/541486/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Run `biber --cache` to get the cache location and delete it.
Then try again, biber will then unpack itself anew.

Comment: Thank you. Confirming (again) this did the trick.

Comment: this answer is golden!

Comment: I'm not sure if my previous "workaround" for this situation -- restarting my computer -- has the same effect as `biber --cache` but I'll definitely try this first, next time (it only happens once every few months).

Comment: To report back, I get this error every few days now, usually after my computer has slept. I use this answer to clear the error and everything works fine. Pretty annoying, though!

Comment: @RicoPicone you could try to change the location where the cache is stored. Imho there is an environment variable you could set.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer, I'll try that. I should write it in as an option to my aux-clearing script, anyway.

Comment: Saved me the weekend. Thanks!

Comment: I really wonder what's causing the problem. This is an effective solution, but if I had the time to investigate I would definitely try to locate the root cause..

Comment: Great answer, thanks. In addition to this, I also had to delete all the aux files after clearing the biber cache in order to get my project to compile properly.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today. Here is another solution.

1. Changed \usepackage[backend=biber,…]{biblatex} to     \usepackage[backend=bibtex,…]{biblatex}
2. Compiled my file
3. Changed back to \usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
4. Compiled again
5. Problem gone

Comment: Sounds like you could have had it easier by just clearing your auxiliary files.  ;-)

Comment: I tried that too, but it didn't remove the problem. ;–)

Comment: using bibtex instead of biber will remove the specific biber features and is normally not recommended.

Comment: @ Ulrike Fischer: I did that for cleaning purposes – instead of putting hands on the files – not for permanent use.