# Biber not writing output to bbl file

Tags: citing, biber

I use Texshop and Texstudio, and `biber`. All of a sudden my citations are not compiling properly. MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4,british,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber,hyperref=false,giveninits=true]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{/Users/fabrec/Dropbox/LATEX/texmf/bibtex/library.bib}
```

Here is the blg message:

```
[0] Config.pm:304> INFO - This is Biber 2.14
[0] Config.pm:307> INFO - Logfile is 'War Dutie to Protect and Military Abolitionism.blg'
[94] biber-darwin:322> INFO - === Sun Mar 21, 2021, 21:58:33
[114] Biber.pm:415> INFO - Reading 'War Dutie to Protect and Military Abolitionism.bcf'
[274] Biber.pm:943> INFO - Found 17 citekeys in bib section 0
[290] Biber.pm:4256> INFO - Processing section 0
[291] Utils.pm:75> INFO - Globbing data source '/Users/fabrec/Dropbox/LATEX/texmf/bibtex/library.bib'
[291] Utils.pm:91> INFO - Globbed data source '/Users/fabrec/Dropbox/LATEX/texmf/bibtex/library.bib' to /Users/fabrec/Dropbox/LATEX/texmf/bibtex/library.bib
[303] Biber.pm:4455> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file '/Users/fabrec/Dropbox/LATEX/texmf/bibtex/library.bib' for section 0
[516] bibtex.pm:1653> INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
[10256] bibtex.pm:1471> INFO - Found BibTeX data source '/Users/fabrec/Dropbox/LATEX/texmf/bibtex/library.bib'
```

I have reinstalled both MacTex and Texstudio, deleted aux and bbl and tried again, etc. It worked fine two days ago.

Comment: I would try the MWE from https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407 and test if your system is in general capable of doing it --> create a new project/document and test it.

Comment: If the test is successful, then you can add more and more code from your actual project until the problem occurs again.

Comment: In addition, consider accepting the given answer to your other old questions.

Comment: The `.blg` so far looks good, but is not complete. Usually this appears to happen when the Biber cache is damaged. Delete the Biber cache as explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/543837/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/541486/35864.

Comment: Thanks everyone. It worked. Cecile