# LyX: Bibliography problem when previewing a PDF

Tags: biblatex, lyx

First of all, I'm sorry for my English (I am Spanish). I am writing my thesis with LyX and managing my references with Zotero. My document class is Book (Standard Class) and **the style format is Biblatex**.
I was following these steps that were working for me:

1. From Zotero, export my bibliography to Biblatex (UTF) in a .bib
   file
2. Import the bibliography in LyX with Insert / List /
   Bib(la)TeX
3. Insert citation
4. Preview the PFD with [PDF(pdflatex]

But yesterday **it stopped working out of the blue** and I haven't touched anything! Now, when I preview the PDF it doesn't show the bibliography index nor the in-text citations (only the Cite key in bold).
This is my document preamble:

```
    #LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass book
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language spanish
\language_package auto
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize 12
\spacing onehalf
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine biblatex
\cite_engine_type authoryear
\biblio_style plain
\biblatex_bibstyle authoryear
\biblatex_citestyle authoryear
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style french
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header
```

I am a bit desperate, please help! Thank you, dear Internet.

Update: I am adding the LaTeX log (Biber):

```
[0] Config.pm:311> INFO - This is Biber 2.16
[0] Config.pm:314> INFO - Logfile is 'Tesis.blg'
[83] biber-darwin:340> INFO - === Sat Oct 23, 2021, 13:57:34
[99] Biber.pm:415> INFO - Reading 'Tesis.bcf'
[211] Biber.pm:952> INFO - Found 52 citekeys in bib section 0
[240] Biber.pm:4340> INFO - Processing section 0
[250] Biber.pm:4531> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file '0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib' for section 0
[255] bibtex.pm:1689> INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
[348] bibtex.pm:1494> INFO - Found BibTeX data source '0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib'
[390] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'hernandez_redondo_diego_2000' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '2000' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[394] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'menendez_gonzalez_traza_2019' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '2019' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[397] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'gomez-moreno_diego_1988' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1988' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[399] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'villacampa_capilla_1928' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1928' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[402] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'marias_franco_largo_1989' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1989' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[405] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'aceto_cappella_2010' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '2010' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[408] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'gaeta_tra_2016' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '2016' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[411] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'naldi_magnificence_2018' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '2018' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[413] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'gomez-moreno_aguilas_1983' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1983' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[416] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'rotili_arte_1976' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1976' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[420] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'strazzullo_edilizia_1968' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1968' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[422] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'leone_de_castris_roma_2015' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '2015' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[425] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'belloso_martin_barrio_2006' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '2006' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[426] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'acerbo_guida_2008' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '2008' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[433] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'migliaccio_consecratio_1994' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1994' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[436] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'tafuri_sobre_1995' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1995' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[439] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'di_resta_sullattivita_1992' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1992' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[442] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'lotz_representacion_1984' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1984' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[444] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'migliaccio_tomba_2017' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '2017' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[449] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'merino_gomez_representacion_2015' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '2015' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[449] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'merino_gomez_representacion_2015' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '2021-09-27' of date field 'urldate' - ignoring
[452] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'ferraro_napoli_2002' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '2002' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[455] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'bologna_problemi_1950' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1950' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[457] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'speranza_sul_2003' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '2003' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[460] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'norman_succorpo_1986' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1986' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[461] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'norman_succorpo_1986' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '2021-09-27' of date field 'urldate' - ignoring
[463] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'godby_note_1980' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1980' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[466] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'dominguez_parela_perspectiva_1991' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1991' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[469] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'toajas_roger_artistas_2007' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '2007' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[472] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'panofsky_perspectiva_1983' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1983' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[476] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'ampliato_use_2020' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '2020' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[478] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'bologna_aggiunta_1988' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1988' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[481] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'zurla_domenico_2013' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '2013' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[484] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'madurell_marimon_bartolome_1948' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1948' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[487] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'gutierrez_martinez_estudio_1973' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1973' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[490] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'sanchez_diana_burgos_1969' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1969' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[492] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'carande_thovar_carlos_1977' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1977' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[495] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'lleo_canal_nueva_1993' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1993' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[498] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'polanco_melero_tensiones_2001' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '2001' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[501] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'lovett_espanprimeros_1986' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1986' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[512] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'zalama_rodriguez_diego_1992' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1992' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[515] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'ampliato_idea_1991' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1991' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[519] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'speranza_escalera_2001' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '2001' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[520] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'speranza_escalera_2001' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '2021-10-04' of date field 'urldate' - ignoring
[523] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'huidobro_serna_artistas_1922' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1922' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[527] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'ruiz_de_la_rosa_control_1986' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1986' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[530] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'marias_franco_problema_1979' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1979' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[533] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'ampliato_muro_1996' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1996' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[537] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'redondo_cantera_luci_2013' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '2013' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[540] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'ainaud_contrato_1948' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1948' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[546] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'martinez_monterio_genesis_2014' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '2014' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[549] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'marias_franco_sobre_1990' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '1990' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[552] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry 'comune_di_napoli_progetto_2014' (0_Users_eacosta_Library_Mobile_Documents_com_ap___022_Doctorado_Texto_Cap__tulo_2_CAPITULO_II.bib): Invalid format '2014' of date field 'date' - ignoring
[554] Utils.pm:395> WARN - I didn't find a database entry for 'touring_club_italiano_napoli_1931' (section 0)
```

Also, in the LaTeX log (LaTeX) I found this warning:

```
Package biblatex Warning: 'babel/polyglossia' detected but 'csquotes' missing.
(biblatex)                Loading 'csquotes' recommended.
```

And this other for every citation:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'hernandez_redondo_diego_2000' on page 1 undefined on i
nput line 26.


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 26--26
[][]\T1/cmr/m/n/10 Para una dis-cu-si�n so-bre la fe-cha de su na-ci-mien-to, v
er
 []
```

Uptade 2: I am adding some screenshots.
The first one is the settings for the bibliography:
[image: Document settings]

The second one, is the problem that I have. Now the citations don't show as expected, instead they appear with the Cite key:
[image: Example of PDF problem]

Comment: Is there any chance you can get hold of the `.log` and `.blg` files? Go to "Document > LaTeX Log" In the window that pops up you can select which log to view at the top under "Log type". Select "Biber" can copy-and-paste the complete contents into your question. Also check the "LaTeX" log for anything suspicious (there are buttons that can take you to warnings and errors).

Comment: @moewe I've updated my post with the logs. Thank you...

Comment: The Biber log shows spurious watrnings and ends prematurely, which is usually sign of a broken cache. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/541486/35864 for more details. Delete the cache as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864 and compile your document again. Note that the first compilation run after you deleted the cache may take much, much longer than usual. Do not abort the run or restart it. Wait until it finishes.

Comment: It works! You've been a fantastic help, THANK YOU @moewe  you saved my day :)