# Problem compiling with Biber

Tags: bibliographies, compiling, biber

I use MikTex on Windows 10 (Texstudio + Jabref)

I have a problem with Biber during the compilation with Xelatex and I get the following message:

> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'Bibliographie.bib'
> ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: C:\Users\UTILIS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\biber_tmp_CYsw\fc1a984cf0c33bbf02ada4c803e0be02_9224.utf8, line 2169, syntax error: found ",", expected one of: number, name (entry type, key, field, or macro name), end of entry ("}" or ")") or quoted string ({...} or "...")
> WARN - Invalid or undefined BibTeX entry key in file 'C:\Users\UTILIS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\biber_tmp_CYsw\fc1a984cf0c33bbf02ada4c803e0be02_9224.utf8', skipping ...
> INFO - WARNINGS: 1
> INFO - ERRORS: 1
> Processus terminé avec une ou plusieurs erreurs

I have read some posts about that problem, which say that it's because of Perl or cache file. I seeked the file with `biber --cache` but it gave me something else:

> C:\Users\UTILIS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\par-5574696c69736174657572\cache-3c6e3d50dacdb14b39eefdbcf10dd20922aae30a

I can't find the file mentionned by the log file. I found the one given by `biber --cache` and tried to delete it but it did not work.

How can I solve this ?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide the tex and bib file so we can look into the problem.

Comment: `syntax error: found ` normally mean that you have some error in your bib.

Comment: How can I join the files to the post ?

Comment: Normally, you can just open your files in your favourite text editor and paste their contents here. Note that the error message says `line 2169`, which suggests your file might be too large to be posted in full.

Comment: The error message you get is usually not caused by the cache bug (the error/behaviour looks different, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/543837/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/541486/35864). You can delete the cache if you like (get rid of the complete folder `C:\Users\UTILIS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\par-5574696c69736174657572\cache-3c6e3d50dacdb14b39eefdbcf10dd20922aae30a`) to be sure, but I'd say this is unlikely to help. ...

Comment: ... According to the error message there is a syntax error in your file. The file name shown in the error message (`biber_tmp_CYsw\fc1a984cf0c33bbf02ada4c803e0be02_9224.utf8`) is that of a temporary copy of your file (`Bibliographie.bib`). The temporary file is likely already gone from the cache. But since it is just a copy of your original file, you can look for the error there. Parsing error messages do not always point to the exact line number where the error is, they point to the line in which the error was encountered. ...

Comment: ... Usually that is a few lines below the real source of the error. Check the entries below and above the line mentioned in the error message for syntax problems. If you can't find any, post the entries here in the question (not the entire file, just the relevant entries around line 2169).

Comment: You were right moewe. There was a mistake in the bib file, though I don't understand how it happened... Now, I still have message about undefined references and messages about "generic hook" that are deprecated, but I can see my references in the pdf. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you get is most likely not caused by a damaged cache (the error/behaviour would look different, e.g. [Biblatex/biber fails with a strange error about missing recode_data.xml file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864), [Very strange error suddenly appeared running Biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/543837/35864), [Biber 2.14 - Puzzling repeated error : "Invalid format '2020-01-01' of date field 'date' - ignoring"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/541486/35864)). You can delete the cache if you like (get rid of the complete folder `C:\Users\UTILIS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\par-5574696c69736174657572\cache-3c6e3d50dacdb14b39eefdbcf10dd20922aae30a`) to be sure, but I'd say this is unlikely to help.

According to the error message, there is a syntax error in your file. The file name shown in the error message (`biber_tmp_CYsw\fc1a984cf0c33bbf02ada4c803e0be02_9224.utf8`) is that of a temporary copy of your file (`Bibliographie.bib`). The temporary file is likely already gone from the cache. But since it is just a copy of your original file, you can look for the error there. Parsing error messages do not always point to the exact line number where the error is, they point to the line in which the error was encountered. Usually that is a few lines below the real source of the error. Check the entries below and above the line mentioned in the error message (line 2169) for syntax problems.