# Problem with Biber, empty bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, texmaker

I am creating my thesis on LaTeX using TexMaker on Mac. I had no problem with references until yesterday. Suddenly, when quoting a reference, it prints the key reference and not the reference : in an author-year bibliography, when I type "\cite{quote1}", it prints "**quote1**". I went through a lot of discussions on this website, and found out that the problem was probably a Biber problem. However, Biber 2.14 is perfectly well installed on my Mac (Tex Live 2020), I changed the configurations on Tekmaker (in the case "Bib(la)Tex" there is "biber" % and the quick compilation is on the button "PdfLatex + Bib(la)tex + PdfLatex + see Pdf.

Here is my file (I am a beginner in LaTex and used a template from a schoolmate who has done a similar thesis) :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside]{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,  bibencoding=utf8,style=authoryear, sorting=nyt, citestyle=authoryear, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=5, giveninits=true, uniquename=init]{biblatex} 

\usepackage{csquotes} 

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\setlength\bibitemsep{\baselineskip}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{%
  andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}
}

\makeatletter

\newrobustcmd*{\parentexttrack}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@blxinit
  \blx@setsfcodes
  \blx@bibopenparen#1\blx@bibcloseparen
  \endgroup}

\AtEveryCite{%
  \let\parentext=\parentexttrack%
  \let\bibopenparen=\bibopenbracket%
  \let\bibcloseparen=\bibclosebracket}

\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblio_test.bib}

\begin{document} 
\newpage

This is a test \cite{test1} \\
Other test : \cite{test2}

\newpage

\section{Bibliography} \label{sec:bibliography}

\appto{\bibsetup}{\sloppy}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,]
```

This is my Biblio_test.bib file :

```
@inbook{test1,
    title = {Test 1},
    author = {Author1},
    year = {2020,
}

@inbook{test2,
    title = {Test 2},
    author = {Author2},
    year = {2020},
}
```

When I run my maintest.tex file, I get the same result with the Quick compilation or running PDFLatex->Biber->PDFLatex->PDFLatex, which is :

*Process started
INFO - This is Biber 2.14 INFO - Logfile is 'maintest.blg' INFO - Reading 'maintest.bcf' INFO - Found 2 citekeys in bib section 0 INFO - Processing section 0 INFO - Globbing data source 'biblio_test.bib' INFO - Globbed data source 'biblio_test.bib' to biblio_test.bib INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'biblio_test.bib' for section 0 INFO - LaTeX decoding ... INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'biblio_test.bib'
Process exited with error(s)*

The error printed is what I see when I open the "maintest.blg" file. However, the bbl file is empty. Maybe the problem is here?
I really don't understand... It found my bib file but somehow can't read it because my bibliography is empty and it only print the citation's keys. Where is the problem? Could you help me please?

Forgive me if my English is not perfectly correct, I am French :)

Comment: The `.blg` file really shouldn't end that abruptly. Delete the Biber cache (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864) and try again.

Comment: It works now !! Thank you very much, I would never have found on my own ^^

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved with the comment.