# My files (.tex and .bib) won't compile with the on VS Code

Tags: biblatex, texlive, compiling

After updating Tex live, my Tex files won't compile with the bibliographies in VS Code. Without the bibliography, it does compile.
I checked that my .tex & .bib file compiles well together in Overleaf, so there is something wrong with my PC settings. I have the followings:

OS: Windows 10
VS Code version: 1.53.1
Extension version: 8.15.0
TeX distribution version: TeX Live 2020

Here is the LaTeX Workshop Output:

```
[23:33:53] Initializing LaTeX Workshop.
[23:33:53] Extension root: c:\Users\희준\.vscode\extensions\james-yu.latex-workshop-8.15.0
[23:33:53] Creating PDF file watcher.
[23:33:55] Creating LaTeX Workshop http and websocket server.
[23:33:55] LaTeX Workshop initialized.
[23:33:55] Current workspace folders: undefined
[23:33:55] Current workspaceRootDir: 
[23:33:55] Found root file from active editor: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.tex
[23:33:55] Root file changed: from undefined to c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.tex
[23:33:55] Start to find all dependencies.
[23:33:55] Root file languageId: latex
[23:33:55] Instantiating a new file watcher for c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.tex
[23:33:55] Creating Bib file watcher.
[23:33:55] Parsing a file and its subfiles: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.tex
[23:33:55] Found .bib file: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\references.bib
[23:33:55] Added to bib file watcher: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\references.bib
[23:33:55] Parsing .bib entries from c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\references.bib
[23:33:55] Parse fls file.
[23:33:55] Cannot find fls file: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.fls
[23:33:55] Server created on 127.0.0.1:49746
[23:33:56] Added to file watcher: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.tex
[23:33:56] Snippet data loaded.
[23:33:56] LaTeX Workshop version: 8.15.0
[23:33:56] BUILD command invoked.
[23:33:56] The document of the active editor: file:///c%3A/Users/%ED%9D%AC%EC%A4%80/Desktop/Latex/test/v2%20test/main.tex
[23:33:56] The languageId of the document: latex
[23:33:56] Current workspace folders: undefined
[23:33:56] Current workspaceRootDir: 
[23:33:56] BUILD command invoked.
[23:33:56] The document of the active editor: file:///c%3A/Users/%ED%9D%AC%EC%A4%80/Desktop/Latex/test/v2%20test/main.tex
[23:33:56] The languageId of the document: latex
[23:33:56] Current workspace folders: undefined
[23:33:56] Current workspaceRootDir: 
[23:33:56] Found root file from active editor: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.tex
[23:33:56] Found root file from active editor: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.tex
[23:33:56] Keep using the same root file: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.tex
[23:33:56] Keep using the same root file: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.tex
[23:33:56] Building root file: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.tex
[23:33:56] Building root file: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.tex
[23:33:56] Build root file c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.tex
[23:33:56] Parsed 12 bib entries from c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\references.bib.
[23:33:57] Recipe step 1: latexmk, -synctex=1,-interaction=nonstopmode,-file-line-error,-pdf,-outdir=c:/Users/희준/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test,c:/Users/희준/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test/main
[23:33:57] Recipe step env: {}
[23:33:57] cwd: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test
[23:33:57] LaTeX build process spawned. PID: 18228.
[23:34:09] LaTeX log parsed with 4 messages.
[23:34:09] Recipe returns with error: 12/null. PID: 18228. message: Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 29 September 2020, version: 4.70b.
Rule 'pdflatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
      'pdflatex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder -output-directory="c:/Users/����/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test"  "c:\Users\����\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.tex"'
------------
Latexmk: Non-existent bbl file 'main.bbl in line'
 No file main.bbl.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'c:/Users/희준/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test/main.pdf'
Latexmk: List of undefined refs and citations:
  Citation 'aldous' on page 1 undefined on input line 16
Rule 'biber main': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'main.bcf'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'biber main'
------------
------------
Running 'biber  "main.bcf"'
------------
Use of uninitialized value in anonymous hash ({}) at C:\Users\����\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4865656a756e65204b696d\cache-485d9ee7398586ce889a97f1d7a34ff027ca8881\inc\lib/Win32/Unicode/File.pm line 337.
Odd number of elements in anonymous hash at C:\Users\����\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4865656a756e65204b696d\cache-485d9ee7398586ce889a97f1d7a34ff027ca8881\inc\lib/Win32/Unicode/File.pm line 337.
Empty String at C:\Users\����\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4865656a756e65204b696d\cache-485d9ee7398586ce889a97f1d7a34ff027ca8881\inc\lib/Biber/LaTeX/Recode.pm line 116.
Latexmk: Failed to find one or more biber source files:
Latexmk: Summary of warnings from last run of *latex:
  Latex failed to resolve 1 citation(s)
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  biber main: Could not find all biber source files for 'main'
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.
C:\texlive\2020\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 12:
perl.exe c:\texlive\2020\texmf-dist\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -pdf "-outdir=c:/Users/����/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test" "c:/Users/����/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test/main"
.
[23:34:09] The environment variable $PATH: C:\Program Files (x86)\NAT Service;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\MEGA-X;C:\Users\희준\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\희준\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\texlive\2020\bin\win32;
[23:34:09] The environment variable $SHELL: undefined
[23:34:09] Cleaning auxiliary files and retrying build after toolchain error.
[23:34:09] File cleaned: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.aux
[23:34:09] File cleaned: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.blg
[23:34:09] File cleaned: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.log
[23:34:09] File cleaned: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.fls
[23:34:09] File cleaned: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.fdb_latexmk
[23:34:09] Recipe step 1: latexmk, -synctex=1,-interaction=nonstopmode,-file-line-error,-pdf,-outdir=c:/Users/희준/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test,c:/Users/희준/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test/main
[23:34:09] Recipe step env: {}
[23:34:09] cwd: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test
[23:34:09] LaTeX build process spawned. PID: 18040.
[23:34:15] LaTeX log parsed with 4 messages.
[23:34:15] Recipe returns with error: 12/null. PID: 18040. message: Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 29 September 2020, version: 4.70b.
Rule 'pdflatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
      'pdflatex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder -output-directory="c:/Users/����/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test"  "c:\Users\����\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.tex"'
------------
Latexmk: Non-existent bbl file 'main.bbl in line'
 No file main.bbl.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'c:/Users/희준/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test/main.pdf'
Latexmk: List of undefined refs and citations:
  Citation 'aldous' on page 1 undefined on input line 16
Rule 'biber main': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'main.bcf'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'biber main'
------------
------------
Running 'biber  "main.bcf"'
------------
Use of uninitialized value in anonymous hash ({}) at C:\Users\����\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4865656a756e65204b696d\cache-485d9ee7398586ce889a97f1d7a34ff027ca8881\inc\lib/Win32/Unicode/File.pm line 337.
Odd number of elements in anonymous hash at C:\Users\����\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4865656a756e65204b696d\cache-485d9ee7398586ce889a97f1d7a34ff027ca8881\inc\lib/Win32/Unicode/File.pm line 337.
Empty String at C:\Users\����\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4865656a756e65204b696d\cache-485d9ee7398586ce889a97f1d7a34ff027ca8881\inc\lib/Biber/LaTeX/Recode.pm line 116.
Latexmk: Failed to find one or more biber source files:
Latexmk: Summary of warnings from last run of *latex:
  Latex failed to resolve 1 citation(s)
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  biber main: Could not find all biber source files for 'main'
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.
C:\texlive\2020\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 12:
perl.exe c:\texlive\2020\texmf-dist\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -pdf "-outdir=c:/Users/����/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test" "c:/Users/����/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test/main"
.
[23:34:15] The environment variable $PATH: C:\Program Files (x86)\NAT Service;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\MEGA-X;C:\Users\희준\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\희준\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\texlive\2020\bin\win32;
[23:34:15] The environment variable $SHELL: undefined
[23:34:15] Build root file c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.tex
[23:34:15] File cleaned: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.aux
[23:34:15] File cleaned: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.fls
[23:34:15] File cleaned: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.blg
[23:34:15] File cleaned: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.log
[23:34:15] File cleaned: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.fdb_latexmk
[23:34:15] Recipe step 1: latexmk, -synctex=1,-interaction=nonstopmode,-file-line-error,-pdf,-outdir=c:/Users/희준/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test,c:/Users/희준/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test/main
[23:34:15] Recipe step env: {}
[23:34:15] cwd: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test
[23:34:15] LaTeX build process spawned. PID: 4884.
[23:34:21] LaTeX log parsed with 4 messages.
[23:34:21] Recipe returns with error: 12/null. PID: 4884. message: Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 29 September 2020, version: 4.70b.
Rule 'pdflatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
      'pdflatex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder -output-directory="c:/Users/����/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test"  "c:\Users\����\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.tex"'
------------
Latexmk: Non-existent bbl file 'main.bbl in line'
 No file main.bbl.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'c:/Users/희준/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test/main.pdf'
Latexmk: List of undefined refs and citations:
  Citation 'aldous' on page 1 undefined on input line 16
Rule 'biber main': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'main.bcf'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'biber main'
------------
------------
Running 'biber  "main.bcf"'
------------
Use of uninitialized value in anonymous hash ({}) at C:\Users\����\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4865656a756e65204b696d\cache-485d9ee7398586ce889a97f1d7a34ff027ca8881\inc\lib/Win32/Unicode/File.pm line 337.
Odd number of elements in anonymous hash at C:\Users\����\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4865656a756e65204b696d\cache-485d9ee7398586ce889a97f1d7a34ff027ca8881\inc\lib/Win32/Unicode/File.pm line 337.
Empty String at C:\Users\����\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4865656a756e65204b696d\cache-485d9ee7398586ce889a97f1d7a34ff027ca8881\inc\lib/Biber/LaTeX/Recode.pm line 116.
Latexmk: Failed to find one or more biber source files:
Latexmk: Summary of warnings from last run of *latex:
  Latex failed to resolve 1 citation(s)
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  biber main: Could not find all biber source files for 'main'
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.
C:\texlive\2020\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 12:
perl.exe c:\texlive\2020\texmf-dist\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -pdf "-outdir=c:/Users/����/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test" "c:/Users/����/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test/main"
.
[23:34:21] The environment variable $PATH: C:\Program Files (x86)\NAT Service;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\MEGA-X;C:\Users\희준\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\희준\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\texlive\2020\bin\win32;
[23:34:21] The environment variable $SHELL: undefined
[23:34:21] Cleaning auxiliary files and retrying build after toolchain error.
[23:34:21] File cleaned: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.aux
[23:34:21] File cleaned: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.blg
[23:34:21] File cleaned: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.log
[23:34:21] File cleaned: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.fls
[23:34:21] File cleaned: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.fdb_latexmk
[23:34:21] Recipe step 1: latexmk, -synctex=1,-interaction=nonstopmode,-file-line-error,-pdf,-outdir=c:/Users/희준/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test,c:/Users/희준/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test/main
[23:34:21] Recipe step env: {}
[23:34:21] cwd: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test
[23:34:21] LaTeX build process spawned. PID: 17716.
[23:34:26] LaTeX log parsed with 4 messages.
[23:34:26] Recipe returns with error: 12/null. PID: 17716. message: Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 29 September 2020, version: 4.70b.
Rule 'pdflatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
      'pdflatex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder -output-directory="c:/Users/����/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test"  "c:\Users\����\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.tex"'
------------
Latexmk: Non-existent bbl file 'main.bbl in line'
 No file main.bbl.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'c:/Users/희준/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test/main.pdf'
Latexmk: List of undefined refs and citations:
  Citation 'aldous' on page 1 undefined on input line 16
Rule 'biber main': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'main.bcf'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'biber main'
------------
------------
Running 'biber  "main.bcf"'
------------
Use of uninitialized value in anonymous hash ({}) at C:\Users\����\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4865656a756e65204b696d\cache-485d9ee7398586ce889a97f1d7a34ff027ca8881\inc\lib/Win32/Unicode/File.pm line 337.
Odd number of elements in anonymous hash at C:\Users\����\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4865656a756e65204b696d\cache-485d9ee7398586ce889a97f1d7a34ff027ca8881\inc\lib/Win32/Unicode/File.pm line 337.
Empty String at C:\Users\����\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4865656a756e65204b696d\cache-485d9ee7398586ce889a97f1d7a34ff027ca8881\inc\lib/Biber/LaTeX/Recode.pm line 116.
Latexmk: Failed to find one or more biber source files:
Latexmk: Summary of warnings from last run of *latex:
  Latex failed to resolve 1 citation(s)
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  biber main: Could not find all biber source files for 'main'
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.
C:\texlive\2020\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 12:
perl.exe c:\texlive\2020\texmf-dist\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -pdf "-outdir=c:/Users/����/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test" "c:/Users/����/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test/main"
.
[23:34:26] The environment variable $PATH: C:\Program Files (x86)\NAT Service;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\MEGA-X;C:\Users\희준\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\희준\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\texlive\2020\bin\win32;
[23:34:26] The environment variable $SHELL: undefined
[23:34:26] File cleaned: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.aux
[23:34:26] File cleaned: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.blg
[23:34:26] File cleaned: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.log
[23:34:26] File cleaned: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.fls
[23:34:26] File cleaned: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.fdb_latexmk
[23:34:28] Current workspace folders: undefined
[23:34:28] Current workspaceRootDir: 
[23:34:28] Found root file from active editor: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.tex
[23:34:28] Keep using the same root file: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.tex
[23:37:43] Current workspace folders: undefined
[23:37:43] Current workspaceRootDir: 
[23:37:43] Found root file from active editor: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.tex
[23:37:43] Keep using the same root file: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.tex
[23:37:49] Current workspace folders: undefined
[23:37:49] Current workspaceRootDir: 
[23:37:49] Found root file from active editor: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.tex
[23:37:49] Keep using the same root file: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.tex
[23:37:51] Current workspace folders: undefined
[23:37:51] Current workspaceRootDir: 
[23:37:51] Found root file from active editor: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.tex
[23:37:51] Keep using the same root file: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.tex
[23:38:23] Current workspace folders: undefined
[23:38:23] Current workspaceRootDir: 
[23:38:23] Found root file from active editor: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.tex
[23:38:23] Keep using the same root file: c:\Users\희준\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.tex
```

Here is the Latex Compiler output:

```
Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 29 September 2020, version: 4.70b.
Rule 'pdflatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
      'pdflatex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder -output-directory="c:/Users/����/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test"  "c:\Users\����\Desktop\Latex\test\v2 test\main.tex"'
------------
Set environment variable BIBINPUTS='c:/Users/����/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test;'
Set environment variable TEXINPUTS='c:/Users/����/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test;'
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(c:/Users/희준/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test/main.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-06> (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsart.cls
Document Class: amsart 2020/05/29 v2.20.6
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty)) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty)) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def)) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx)) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric.cbx) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def) (c:/Users/희준/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test/main.aux) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-2020-10-01.sty (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-generic.tex))))
No file main.bbl.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'aldous' on page 1 undefined on input line 16.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 24.

[1{c:/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (c:/Users/희준/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test/main.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                main
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

 )<c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb><c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb>
Output written on "c:/Users/희준/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test/main.pdf" (1 page, 26961 bytes).
SyncTeX written on c:/Users/����/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test/main.synctex.gz.

Transcript written on "c:/Users/희준/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test/main.log".
Latexmk: Non-existent bbl file 'main.bbl in line'
 No file main.bbl.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'c:/Users/희준/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test/main.pdf'
Latexmk: List of undefined refs and citations:
  Citation 'aldous' on page 1 undefined on input line 16
Rule 'biber main': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'main.bcf'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'biber main'
------------
------------
Running 'biber  "main.bcf"'
------------
Latexmk: Examining 'c:/Users/����/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test/main.log'
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: applying rule 'biber main'...
Use of uninitialized value in anonymous hash ({}) at C:\Users\����\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4865656a756e65204b696d\cache-485d9ee7398586ce889a97f1d7a34ff027ca8881\inc\lib/Win32/Unicode/File.pm line 337.
Odd number of elements in anonymous hash at C:\Users\����\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4865656a756e65204b696d\cache-485d9ee7398586ce889a97f1d7a34ff027ca8881\inc\lib/Win32/Unicode/File.pm line 337.
Empty String at C:\Users\����\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4865656a756e65204b696d\cache-485d9ee7398586ce889a97f1d7a34ff027ca8881\inc\lib/Biber/LaTeX/Recode.pm line 116.
INFO - This is Biber 2.16
INFO - Logfile is 'main.blg'
Latexmk: Failed to find one or more biber source files:
Latexmk: Summary of warnings from last run of *latex:
  Latex failed to resolve 1 citation(s)
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  biber main: Could not find all biber source files for 'main'
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
C:\texlive\2020\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 12:
perl.exe c:\texlive\2020\texmf-dist\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -pdf "-outdir=c:/Users/����/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test" "c:/Users/����/Desktop/Latex/test/v2 test/main"
```

This is driving me nuts. Please help me.

Comment: This looks like your Biber cache is corrupted. Delete the cache as explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864 and try again. After deleting the cache the next Biber/`latexmk` could take a lot longer than usual, do not stop the compilation in that case, wait and let it complete.

Comment: @moewe  Thanks for your commment. I deleted the cache as indicated, but I still get the error message. Should I ask about this in a new post?

Comment: I don't think a new question would help. But unfortunately, I'm out of ideas if deleting the cache doesn't help. Does your `.bib` file name contain non-Latin characters? (Your user name appears to contain non-Latin characters, which shouldn't be an issue, so I figured I might ask.)

Comment: @moewe No, it's in English.

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem with you. But I've solved this problem by moving the file to local folder because I saved my file in oneDrive folder.