# VS Code LaTeX Workshop Error with Biber and Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biber, vscode

despite numerous attempts and following the official documentation to modify the settings.json, I can no longer compile tex documents that use biber+biblatex in VS Code. I keep getting the error "Recipe terminated with error".

The error and accompanying logs pasted below occurred when trying to compile this biblatex template: https://de.overleaf.com/latex/examples/the-chicago-citation-style-with-biblatex/pdqqrmwtdqpc with biblatex and biber:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{sample}
```

Thank you very much and kind regards!

Here is my log:

```
    Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 21 September 2021, version: 4.75.
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'c:/Users/ms/Downloads/The Chicago Citation Style with biblatex/main.tex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder  "c:\Users\ms\Downloads\The Chicago Citation Style with biblatex\main.tex"'
------------
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(c:/Users/ms/Downloads/The Chicago Citation Style with biblatex/main.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15>
L3 programming layer <2021-11-12> (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.def) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.cfg)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric.cbx) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def) (./main.aux) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty))
No file main.bbl.
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/ot1lmr.fd) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omllmm.fd) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omslmsy.fd) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omxlmex.fd)

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Ful83' on page 1 undefined on input line 20.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'GMP81' on page 1 undefined on input line 20.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'GMP81' on page 1 undefined on input line 21.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Pat85' on page 1 undefined on input line 22.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'PP98' on page 1 undefined on input line 22.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'PP95' on page 1 undefined on input line 22.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 24.

[1{c:/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./main.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                main
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

 ){c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-ec.enc}<c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmbx10.pfb><c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmbx12.pfb><c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr10.pfb><c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr12.pfb><c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr17.pfb>
Output written on main.pdf (1 page, 125892 bytes).
SyncTeX written on main.synctex.gz.

Transcript written on main.log.
Latexmk: Missing bbl file 'main.bbl' in following:
 No file main.bbl.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'main.pdf'
Latexmk: List of undefined refs and citations:
  Citation 'Ful83' on page 1 undefined on input line 20
  Citation 'GMP81' on page 1 undefined on input line 20
  Citation 'GMP81' on page 1 undefined on input line 21
  Citation 'PP95' on page 1 undefined on input line 22
  Citation 'PP98' on page 1 undefined on input line 22
  Citation 'Pat85' on page 1 undefined on input line 22
Rule 'biber main': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'main.bcf'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'biber main'
------------
------------
Running 'biber  "main.bcf"'
------------
Latexmk: Examining 'main.log'
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: applying rule 'biber main'...
Couldn't load any math lib(s), not even fallback to Calc.pm at C:\Users\ms\AppData\Local\Temp\par-6d73\cache-485d9ee7398586ce889a97f1d7a34ff027ca8881\19c9b262.pm line 25.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Users\ms\AppData\Local\Temp\par-6d73\cache-485d9ee7398586ce889a97f1d7a34ff027ca8881\19c9b262.pm line 25.
Compilation failed in require at C:\Users\ms\AppData\Local\Temp\par-6d73\cache-485d9ee7398586ce889a97f1d7a34ff027ca8881\3ff52501.pm line 14.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Users\ms\AppData\Local\Temp\par-6d73\cache-485d9ee7398586ce889a97f1d7a34ff027ca8881\3ff52501.pm line 14.
Compilation failed in require at C:\Users\ms\AppData\Local\Temp\par-6d73\cache-485d9ee7398586ce889a97f1d7a34ff027ca8881\de273e16.pm line 20.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Users\ms\AppData\Local\Temp\par-6d73\cache-485d9ee7398586ce889a97f1d7a34ff027ca8881\de273e16.pm line 20.
Compilation failed in require at C:\Users\ms\AppData\Local\Temp\par-6d73\cache-485d9ee7398586ce889a97f1d7a34ff027ca8881\18f3917b.pm line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Users\ms\AppData\Local\Temp\par-6d73\cache-485d9ee7398586ce889a97f1d7a34ff027ca8881\18f3917b.pm line 8.
Compilation failed in require at /loader/HASH(0x28b964c)/parent.pm line 16.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Users\ms\AppData\Local\Temp\par-6d73\cache-485d9ee7398586ce889a97f1d7a34ff027ca8881\7faadb4e.pm line 5.
Compilation failed in require at script/biber-MSWIN32 line 17.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at script/biber-MSWIN32 line 17.
Latexmk: Summary of warnings from last run of *latex:
  Latex failed to resolve 6 citation(s)
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  biber main: Could not open biber log file for 'main'
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.
C:\texlive\2021\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 12:
perl.exe c:\texlive\2021\texmf-dist\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -pdf "-outdir=c:/Users/ms/Downloads/The Chicago Citation Style with biblatex" "c:/Users/ms/Downloads/The Chicago Citation Style with biblatex/main"
```

Comment: Delete the cache (cache-485d9ee7398586ce889a97f1d7a34ff027ca8881) and then try to run biber once manually, then it should unpack itself anew. Perhaps it then work.

Comment: Thank you, running biber once manually worked. The trick was to run "biber <filename>" rather than "biber <filename>.tex".

Comment: biber works on bcf or bib files, see also your log which says `biber  "main.bcf"`, if you leave out the extension it will assume bcf.

Comment: Just to understand the solution: Did you delete the cache as Ulrike suggested or did you resolve the problem without deleting the cache? `latexmk` automatically runs Biber on the correct file name, so this is not the root cause of the original error message.

Comment: I did delete the cache on one project where this error occurred, but I also didn't delete the cache on one other project with the same error, and it also worked, so I assume it's not a must. What I did on both was to run ``biber` first in command line (`latexmk` always tried to run `pdflatex => biber > 2* pdflatex` and aborted during the first `pdflatex`).

Comment: The Biber cache is global on your machine, so you would not have to clear it separately for different projects. The log posted in the question does not show an error that aborted anything in the pdfLaTeX run. The issues only occurred in the Biber run. Taking all that into account I'd suggest closing this question as a duplicate of our standard "delete the Biber cache" question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864.

Comment: @moewe I just re-encountered this and can confirm that deleting the cache manually was indeed necessary to solve it.