# Citation with Biber and BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am now struggling for 2 days with the bibliography and citation in biblatex. After compiling there is no bibliography and instead of citation the cite-key appears in bold. The following shows parts of the codes used:

```
\documentclass[11pt,ngerman,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[extendedfeature=title]{scrextend}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=3cm, top=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[nohyperlinks, printonlyused, withpage]{acronym}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\newcommand*{\mcite}[1]{\citeauthor{#1} (\citeyear{#1})}
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{srmbiber.bib}


\begin{document}
My cite atempt \cite{Keith2015}
    
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

My .bib file: srmbiber.bib looks like this:

```
@Article{Keith2015,
    author  = {Keith, D.W. and MacMartin, D.G.},
    journal = {Nature Climate Change},
    title   = {A temporary, moderate and responsive scenario for solar geoengineering},
    year    = {2015},
    number  = {3},
    pages   = {1758-6798},
    volume  = {5},
    doi     = {10.1038/nclimate2493},
    url     = {https://doi.org/10.1038/nclimate2493},
}
```

I allready tried the following:

- compile with pdflatex - biber - pdflatex - pdflatex
- change the settings in my editor (texstudio), so that biber is the default
- backend=bibtex
- looked into various log files (.blg is empty)

Repeating error messages:

- .bbl not created (though I found it and it was empty)
- Invalid or undefined BibTeX entry key in file...

Does anyone have an idea, what the problem might be about?

Comment: `citestyle=apa` alone is not a good idea. If you want real APA style, you need to go for `style=apa`. Otherwise you end up with a messy mixture of styles.

Comment: Forget your complex document for the moment and try a truly minimal example like https://gist.github.com/moewew/2677f89eb454e33828500e94c14087fb on your machine. You do not have to change *anything* about this file. The `.bib` file that is loaded in the example is already available on your machine (if `biblatex` is installed correctly) and will be found automatically. Do not change the file in any way. Compile it with pdfLaTeX, Biber, pdfLaTeX, pdfLaTeX. Check the `.log` and `.blg` files if the output is not as expected.

Comment: First steps for diagnosing Biber issues are at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864. A relatively common issue are cache problems, so you might want to follow the steps in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864 to delete the cache.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286706/troubleshooting-for-biber this page solved the problem, thank you @moewe ! I am not completely sure but I think it was about an entry in the .bib file which was not complete (only author)