# I can't get my bibliography to work running biber on TexShop on a Mac

Tags: bibliographies, biber, mac, texshop

My citations were printing fine on an academic article I'm about to submit, running TexShop on a Mac, and then suddenly they wouldn't anymore. To troubleshoot, I deleted the last few citations I added, both to the text and to the `.bib` file. Now I discovered I can't even get a simple bibliography to print for anything to work now on old papers, or for this minimum (non-) working example.

I get an error: "LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references."

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{example,
  author  = {Other, Anthony Norman},
  title   = {Some things I did},
  year    = {2014},
  journal = {J.~Irrep. Res.},
  volume  = {1},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {1-10}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Hello\cite{example}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

^I do not get a bibliography from this example. I have set up my editor to run biber (see screenshot below), which was the answer to someone else having this exact problem.

[image]

I also realize I need to first run latex, and then bibtex, and then latex twice more.

Lastly, as per a helpful commenter, here is the .blg file.

[image]

Comment: Compile the example in a new, empty directory. You need to compile this document with LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (where LaTeX can be any LaTeX flavour: in this case most likely pdfLaTeX). If you ran Biber correctly, there should be a `.blg` file. Open that file (it is a simple text file) and add its *complete* content to the question.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've added the .blg file. And I did run Latex twice. Somehow, today, everything works. I spent 6 hours troubleshooting yesterday, to no avail, and today, it simply works as it used it.

Comment: Yesterday, I had also solved the issue by simply switching to running TeXworks on an old PC instead of TeXshop on my mac. I still have no idea why it wouldn't run yesterday but it does today. I didn't do anything different that I know of. Perhaps it was my prayers to the old gods and the new.

Comment: The `.blg` file is not complete. It should also have a line `INFO - Output to XXX.bbl`. Usually that means that the cache is damaged. This is an especially common appearance on Mac OS. If this problem appears the next time, delete the cache as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864, then rerun (the following run might take longer than usual, just let it finish).