# latexmk - command not found on OS X

Tags: mactex, mac, latexmk

I've installed the MacTex bundle on my machine.
When I try to run $latexmk I get a 'command not found'.

I already reinstalled the latexmk bundle in TeX Live Utility.
Both *universal-darwin* and *X86_64-darwin* are installed. But I still get the same error.

I would be very thankful for any solutions.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you calling `latexmk` from the Terminal?

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` give? Have you rebooted since installing MacTeX? (I'm not sure how it manages `PATH` these days on OS X so rebooting might not be relevant.)

Answer (score 10):

I am using OX X Yosemite and I encountered exactly the same problem as you. I solved it by following steps:

1. Launch TeX Live Utility
2. Search for `latexmk` in the filter
3. Check whether `latexmk` is installed in the package tab (for me it shows not installed)
4. Install it with right click and type `latexmk` terminal to check

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Except that the question explicitly states that this is not the problem. Of course, the OP could be lying or deluded, but we have to start somewhere.

Comment: Where do I get TeX Live Utility?

Answer (score 6):

`which latexmk
/Library/TeX/texbin/latexmk`

`cd /Library/TeX/texbin/`  see if it's there.  Add it to your path.  You can git latexmk as well and put it somewhere you like maybe `/usr/local/bin`  the instructions are here [Textmate + Latexmk](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10107/textmate-latexmk?rq=1)

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, if you installed `latexmk` by way of `tlmgr install latexmk`, it may not add it to a location that is in your PATH by default. This can be resolved with `tlmgr path add`.