# macvim, mactex, and M1 MacBook Air (MBA)

Tags: mac, mactex, vim, vim-latex

I'm struggling with using macvim and mactex on M1 MBA.

Here is what I've done.

1. Install macvim (via homebrew, probably).
2. Install [mactex](http://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html).
3. Install TeXShop 4.58, Ghostscript-9.53.3-Full.pkg, and MacTeX-2020-Universal.pkg (see [this](http://www.tug.org/mactex/aboutarm.html)).

However, on my macvim, the following errors occur.

[image]

Note: I tested x86_64 and arm64 support described at the bottom of [this](http://www.tug.org/mactex/aboutarm.html).

Note2: `which latexmk` gives `latexmk not found`.

EDIT: I've installed `latexmk` via `Tex Live Utility` but still the command `latexmk` does not work.

[image]

EDIT2: I manually adding path in `~/.zshrc` as `export PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-darwin:$PATH"`, which solves the problem.

Comment: It is possible the path is not updated. (See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255753/latexmk-command-not-found-on-os-x

Comment: @WillieWong As you pointed out, I found that the path is the reason. Thanks a lot :)